# How to overload optional boolean in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to infer some types for working with a combobox component.

Basically, given a type `T`, the options should be `T[]`, and an onChange handler should be `(value: T) => void`. However, if the `isMulti` flag is true, then onChange should be `(value: T[]) => void`.  I'm just unsure as to how to configure the overloading types to get this to work properly:

```ts
type Options<T = any> = {
    options: T[]
} & ({
    isMulti?: false
    onChange: (value: T) => void
} | {
    isMulti: true
    onChange: (value: T[]) => void
})

interface Option {
    value: string,
}

const a: Options<Option> = {
    // isMulti: false,
    options: [{
        value: 'abc',
    }],
    onChange: (value) => console.log(value)
}
```

See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzgHgCpQLxQEMUQA+PKAbwCgpaol5l0AuKLAbQF0qBfKAMigAKanSgI0AWQCuAG0QB+VgDMCstBBp1UAYQAWRAOYRWQgG5rpJtgEo8ZM0gQATXlAA+lLbQkz5CVmAAJytvehR9I2tzS2sOTjtcBydXHhsqKgQUYAgg1QBjaDhEVC8xC1krVjRgrMMAGl4M-NQawlZipkxO1DJ8UToAekHxKTlEFTUNRrEGEpYodgGxWgqqqAByAgAjfI2Zuh5OA9pdAxRjUzWIRLIW9CRZCAA6WSRDGMqb3iA)

Basically the issue is that if `isMulti` is undefined, then the value in onChange is `any`!

> Parameter 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Is there any way to do this, or do I need to make `isMulti` required?

Comment: Interesting. I am wondering if this could ever work. As far as I know, TypeScript simply compiles to JavaScript. Any types, interfaces etc. are just for type checking purposes during compilation. But it seems to me you are trying to capture some run-time behavior in your type here. What would you actually expect to happen if `a.isMulti` will be changed somewhere else afterwards? TypeScript will not be able to check that, I guess. The emitted JavaScript code will be running, and it will not be aware of your original TypeScript constructs at all.

Comment: It's not really that interesting; using overloads is pretty common practice.  I'm just curious as to how to get it to work with `undefined` as a type.  **Note** in the typescript playground you can set isMulti to true or false and the onChange function is typed correctly.

Comment: setting `"strictNullChecks": true`, in tsconfig could do the job. While it's false both `isMulti: true` and `isMulti: false` can be assigned undefined.

Comment: strictNullChecks is on by default on TypeScript Playground

Comment: @bozdoz I have updated my answer, Please take a look, I believe this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that we had to add extra generic to `onChange` method with constraint:

```js
type A<T> = {
    isMulti: false,
    onChange: (value: T) => any
}
type B<T> = {
    isMulti: true,
    onChange: (value: T[]) => any

}
type C<T> = {
    onChange: (value: T) => any
}

// credits goes to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/struggling-with-building-a-type-in-ts#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Unions<T> = StrictUnion<A<T> | B<T> | C<T>>

type Options<T = any> = {
    options: T[]
} & Unions<T>

interface Option {
    value: string,
}

const a: Options<Option> = {
    options: [{
        value: 'abc',
    }],

// trick is here
    onChange: <T extends Option>(value: T) => {
        return value
    }
}

const b: Options<Option> = {
    isMulti: true,
    options: [{
        value: 'abc',
    }],
    onChange: <T extends Option[]>(value: T) => {
        return value
    }
}
const c: Options<Option> = {
    isMulti: false,
    options: [{
        value: 'abc',
    }],
    onChange: <T extends Option>(value: T) => {
        return value
    }
}

// error because if isMulti is false, value should be Option and not an array of Option
const d: Options<Option> = {
    isMulti: false,
    options: [{
        value: 'abc',
    }],
    // should be T extends Option instead of T extends Option[]
    onChange: <T extends Option[]>(value: T) => {
        return value
    }
}

a.onChange({ value: 'hello' }) // ok
b.onChange([{ value: 'hello' }]) // ok
c.onChange({ value: 'hello' }) // ok
c.onChange([{ value: 'hello' }]) // expected error
```

If you want to understand this trick, please read [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65550146/how-typescript-infers-callbacks-arguments-type)

Comment: The problem as I see it is that I want to know the value type in the definition of the variable `a`, which I see you've typed as `any` here.  It's a neat solution however.  Didn't think of trying to get `infer` to work for me.  Thanks for the perspective; however, I need `onChange` to be aware of the sibling `options` type and the `isMulti` type.  Surprised there doesn't seem to be a good way to do this.

Comment: This is possible to do with extra function.  Are you agree on function overhead?

Comment: I tried separating the interfaces like in your example, and I've posted a solution.  Take a look and hopefully you can improve it. :)

Comment: Second solution is a surprising number of "tricks", which I don't understand.  That `onChange: <T,>(value: T)` is especially bizarre.  Also makes the `onChange` functions useless: Try returning `value.value` or `value.length` instead of `value`: should be able to do one of those, but because it's typed as `T`, neither works.

Comment: @bozdoz my bad. But it is very easy to fix. I made a small update which helps you to understand this trick. Also I added constarints to generic to make it work as you expect

Answer (score 0):

I may have a workaround, though I don't know if it's the best solution.  I tried explicit types for each scenario and defined an overloaded function to pass the object through (though I would love to have this work without the impractical function):

```
interface Option {
    value: string,
}

// default Options
type Options<T = Option> = {
    options: T[]
}

// isMulti is undefined
type U<T> = {
    onChange: (value: T) => void
}

// isMulti is false
type F<T> = {
    isMulti: false
} & U<T>

// isMulti is true
type M<T> = {
    isMulti: true
    onChange: (value: T[]) => void
}

// overloads for determining given parameters
function getOptions<T>(options: Options<T> & M<T>): typeof options;
function getOptions<T>(options: Options<T> & U<T>): typeof options;
function getOptions<T>(options: Options<T> & F<T>): typeof options;
function getOptions(options: any) {
    return options;
}

const a = getOptions({
    // isMulti: false,
    options: [{
        value: 'abc',
    }],
    onChange: (value) => console.log(value)
})
```

This works as I would hope, but it still seems like overkill, and I'm not sure if this works for props for a JSX/React component, for example.

View on typescript playground ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYmQbwChkTkA3OAGwFcIAuZAZzClAHMAaQgX0MIHp%20yACYR41SmDSYcIRoTABPdCgxZcjADwAVZAF5p6kAD59BYqWwyNDbQG0Aujz6DkwRgFkJWN42TUQURhQCGEFZRQAVR1TAyJSZFwAYQALOBA2emQACgoaLO0ASn1TMmxgMN4BIXcvSWBfZHhKRghwlWQAMRizeNJa72AGZtaeZAAyZGjtYxcaz0HGllp2lA8euIsSAfqGZbaE5LSMrNyqWltHYr1S8sq5xLJoSmw4YT8YbCgRCEgoAFtQOxkGxgE88Og4FA4P9ftB5DAAggjCDfmpZFoZtkrEZGAx0RoepN1jNCnsItgYIlrHIANyEREgZGyVFgAlyGLYml4wwYolTGJk5BKFSU6m4%20mM5m4VnszHGLm4-Hc-ndUnk0VUnEYyVIlGZNncxUYhjpRTFPokKC-ahQPDajT0qoIDRSOBmA1y7KW5CuHZYYZUVpcQ7chh2H0JPIXZAAcjgACMELGQ6RuA5UyQjulMgwzvlrqYXXJsJQIAA6F5sfO0Qo8QpAA))

Comment: YOur solution is perfectly fine. Just add `type Base<T> = Options<T> & (F<T> | U<T> | M<T>)` Base type instead of `any` in your function declaration