# Type union not checking for excess properties

Tags: typescript

let's imagine a have an object that either have properties `A` and `B` or `C`, e.g.:

```
const temp = {
  A: 1,
  B: 2,
}
```

or

```
const temp = {
  C: 3,
}
```

And intuitively I see this type as:

```
type T =  {A: number, B: number} | {C: number};

const valid: T = {A: 1, B: 2};
const alsoValid: T = {C: 3};

// Should complain but it does not
const invalid: T  = {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3};
// Also should complain
const alsoInvalid: T = {A:1, C: 3};
```

But TS treats such type as `{A?: number, B?: number, C?: number}` and basically `|` makes fields optional but I want TS to complain about inconsistent type when I add `C` property to `A` and `B`

---

How can I achieve the desirable type?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36945

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a bit of a quirk in how unions work in conjunction with excess property checks. `{A:1, C: 3}` is actually compatible with `{C: number}` except for excess property checks:

```
const o = {A:1, C: 3};
const ok: {C: number} = o; // No direct literal assignment, no excess property checks
const nok: {C: number} = { A:1, C: 3}; // Excess property checks kick in
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8CCAuAjAGhgYXRgGYBfAbgChRJYQBrQ5AmMAVwFsAjAUwCcTEcStWgt6jZmy58BSZDAw58hUmRgB6dTACiAD2DcIEGAAdeIE3ygBPGMAAW3YHWN0Als5huwMIA)

And the quirk of excess property checks is that for unions, it allows any property from *any* union constituent to be present in the assigned object literal.

You can get an error if the union constituents are incompatible one with another:

```
type T =  {A: number, B: number} | {C: number, A?: undefined, B?: undefined };

const valid: T = {A: 1, B: 2};
const alsoValid: T = {C: 3};

// Error
const invalid: T  = {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3};
//Error
const alsoInvalid: T = {A:1, C: 3};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UoG8CCAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnAGigCFNdCSBfKAHxQGFr8iypUB+THLABMIAMwCWWCIPIU+UAcPGTBUOgG4AUBoDGAeywBnYFABuAQwA2YwZjiI0mAIwzMAJnU79RqJYO6AapbWtgismADMHhoA9NFQAKLExLrEnobGEuZWNrBI9hhQzpRu5GxQkZqxicmpeuk+Fn4AklhZwbn56EVlFUA)

You can also use the `StrictUnion` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52678379/125734) if the union has a lot of memebers

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends any ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type T =  StrictUnion<{A: number, B: number} | {C: number }>;

const valid: T = {A: 1, B: 2};
const alsoValid: T = {C: 3};

// Error
const invalid: T  = {A: 1, B: 2, C: 3};
//Error
const alsoInvalid: T = {A:1, C: 3};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAqgOwJYHsEGkpgM4B4AqAfDALwz4xQAeIUCAJtuTAPwwDWWKAZswFwwEUAG5QATgG5QkWAGUQYpAGMQiVAgASUADbQxBADTkAgtu3EyFarQZMAhgjCtmAMhgAFO2JBI723ABKUEooYvS4AKJUStoArvRQuGpomDgEpuZGnGA85IRGQqJihMQCheJS4NAw8ooqyQgEFjUKyqrIaFq64oZ5wNLVFGQtde3quADexmWxALYARuJGAEIzC+IAvjAAPjATAMJri2IwG4RSwCEI2CAwwn5I9AJDe9MwAIwrAgBMG1JXNxgfmwKAAag8nswyAcBABmP79AD0iJgETEYlClzQgKQCHu2kezxgpFeAk+MFWMG+RkOMHhUmRaIxYix11uwJQAEk8RCidDpuTafSgA)

Comment: I believe your solution is more elegant

Comment: I would just add small correction to this statement: "And the quirk of excess property checks is that for unions (*except discriminated unions*), it allows any property from any union constituent to be present in the assigned object literal", as shown in the other answer.

Answer (score 5):

I just always add some `type` of union. For example:

```js
type T = { A: number, B: number, type: 'ONE' } | { C: number, type: 'TWO' };


const valid: T = { A: 1, B: 2, type: 'ONE' };
const alsoValid: T = { C: 3, type: 'TWO' };

// Should complain but it does not
const invalid: T = { A: 1, B: 2, C: 3, type: "ONE" };
// Also should complain
const alsoInvalid: T = { A: 1, C: 3, type: 'TWO' };
```

The goal is to have some common property

Comment: Making a discriminated union is definitely also a valid idea

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir do you mind if I link your solution `StrictUnion` in my ts blog?

Comment: Hey @captain-yossarian 
that looks interesting. Never heard of the `never` type. Thanks for that. I guess I can go with that.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine You may want to add a comment that this approach fails when `type` is dynamic, i.e. `const shouldComplain: T = { A: 1, C: 3, B:6, type: Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'TWO':"ONE" };` no error here.