# Make a property required when another property is defined (discriminated union)

Tags: typescript

I want to write a type that allows for object creation with some core properties that are always required and an optional property `imageUrl` which when defined as a string means `imageAltText` is also required as a string,

```
{
 id: "test",
 imageUrl: "test",
 imageAltText: "test"
}
```

I also want it to work so that when `imageUrl` is not defined I do not expect `imageAltText` to be defined.

```
{
 id: "test"
}
```

I've defined the type as the following,

```
(
  {
    /** image url for the banner of the card. Will display a blue background without an image */
    imageUrl?: undefined;
  } 
| 
  {
    /** image url for the banner of the card. Will display a blue background without an image */
    imageUrl: string;
      /** alternative text for the banner image */
    imageAltText: string;
  }
)

However, by making `imageUrl` optional `?` typescript allows me to write `imageAltText` even when `imageUrl` is undefined.
```

Answer (score 3):

Here you have:

```js
type RequiredParams<T = {}> = {
    id: string
} & T

type UnionParams =
    | RequiredParams<{ imageUrl: string; imageAltText: string; }>
    | RequiredParams

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Result = StrictUnion<UnionParams>

const a: Result = { id: 'sdf' }; // ok
const b: Result = { id: 'sdf', imageUrl: 'sdf', imageAltText: 'sdf' } // ok
const c: Result = { id: 'sdf', imageUrl: 'sdf' } // error
const d: Result = { id: 'sdf', imageAltText: 'sdf' } // error
```

All gredits goes to [@Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/struggling-with-building-a-type-in-ts#answer-65805753)

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. Though I'm surprised we have to use so many helpers for this.

Comment: You can consider @Lesiak 's solutions. Maybe sometime there is a simpler solutions. There are a lot of TS issues which could be solved in several ways

Answer (score 2):

```
type ForbidProps<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: never;
}

type OptionalImagePart = {
  imageUrl: string;
  imageAltText: string;
}

type Image =   { id: number; } & (OptionalImagePart | ForbidProps<OptionalImagePart>)

const image1Ok: Image = {
  id: 1
}

const image2Ok: Image = {
  id: 1,
  imageUrl: 'imageUrl',
  imageAltText: 'imageAltText' 
}

const image3Error: Image = { // Expected error
  id: 1,
  imageUrl: 'imageUrl' 
}

const image4Error: Image = { // Expected error
  id: 1,
  imageAltText: 'imageAltText' 
}
```