# type that can be ONE of multiple key typescript

Tags: typescript

I have an interface

```
 interface Test {
   property: SpecialProperty;
 }
```

now `SpecialProperty` can be ONE of each :

```
export type SpecialProperty= {
      withPropA: PropA;
    }
  | {
      withPropB: PropB;
    }
  | {
      withPropC: PropC;
    }
```

there can't be `withPropA` and another property etc..

The problem is the compiler do not allow me to do this.

if I do

```
function(param: Test ) {
 if(param.property.withPropA) {
   const prop:PropA = param.property.withPropA;
 }
 if(param.property.withPropB) {
   const prop:PropB = param.property.withPropB;
 }

}
```

the compiler say

> Property 'withPropA' does not exist on type '{
> withPropB: PropB;
> }'.

I tried casting etc... but nothing

Comment: The issue isn't the "one of" part, it's accessing a property that doesn't exist on every member of the union.  You can do `if("withPropA" in param.property) {` which is a type guard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html

Comment: @LindaPaiste - Sadly, that page doesn't (any longer?) show this kind of check (lots of others, but not this kind). I haven't found the page that does (now). :-| Certainly they *should* be on that page...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know!  I went to pull up the old link and saw the big "deprecated" banner but the old page had more sections on it.  Didn't want to link to a deprecated page but..."Using the `in` Operator": https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator

Comment: @LindaPaiste - Doh! Why didn't I just link to the deprecated page?! :-) I'm not 100% today, clearly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a property existence check to narrow the type of `param.property` rather than a truthiness check:

```typescript
function example(param: Test ) {
    if ("withPropA" in param.property) {                  // ***
        const prop:PropA = param.property.withPropA;
    }
    if ("withPropB" in param.property) {                  // ***
        const prop:PropB = param.property.withPropB;
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAQSgXigZ2HAlgOwHMBuAKFElkTACF0p8BXAWwCMI4yLp4kBheqwQIANhACG%20MqQLAOAM3EBjaABUI2KAG9SUPVDDUOoAFxQAypCW5xI3pDigyAX1Llw0SxGu37xkOi6%20jr6%20gDuuMAAFvbIZrFkoc5QAD5BeiGh4ZEx1DTxeYn6yWmhmVlQEdH2fAX8RXrO0qTyjPhKwLgI%20FAQAB7izGBiABRg4nCDZuqaAJTa6VC48lAjAERVuUjIa0s945PMAHSGSP7z5VlK3ZqnYCax9AeDJ0aOIEebCYuuocurGxy9houwIBgmLzu5wWFT013wt2oDzyTwhxyh70%20QMKP1IriAA)

Your truthiness check required that you read the value of the property, but TypeScript doesn't know whether the object has that property when you ask it to do that.

More [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator). That page is supposedly deprecated in favor of [this page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) now, but the new page doesn't cover this particular check (yet, the new page is **brand** new).

Answer (score 0):

To go with union types, you should declare some common property for all unions.

For example `type` or `kind`.

See next example:

```js
interface Test {
    property: SpecialProperty;
}

type PropA = 'a'
type PropB = 'b'
type PropC = 'c'


//https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions
export type SpecialProperty =
    | {
        type: 'A',
        withPropA: PropA;
    }
    | {
        type: 'B',
        withPropB: PropB;
    }
    | {
        type: 'C'
        withPropC: PropC;
    }


function test(param: Test) {
    if (param.property.type === 'A') {
        const prop: PropA = param.property.withPropA;
    }
    if (param.property.type === 'B') {
        const prop: PropB = param.property.withPropB;
    }

}
```

Because this is how [TypeScript discrimunated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) works

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwLABQyxyADlAPanRgCeAXMgMrULBwA2ACpdVHQG5CAX0KE61ZDyoBBZAF5kAcjhLxtSdNIAhBcoBGaghJRaAwnqUIjYggHo7ACzBhSGeg4Du3gHQmMCFDApGAccCAA5j4UUBF2ACYUCBhO4fH6FBQA1nb%20gcFgALSghQCshQC2oACukBiFMNUgCD7OFRwAxPHAAUFVIHCQ8YVNwBQgGIQQAB6kMdgmzKzs3Lw0tAqEJMgAPrhb2yQmjEoySgA0B4fInsBgjloyjI9CRCSib8R7%20J%20Hx8raC5XQ63e5abTPXjaV7bD7bb7A7b-JRmIzXYigh68MyQqhmGHvWyERrNMBjEDIOpgAAUpDgUDgFUY6CwAEp9r9gDBkLT6YyfOQqOs-BoUPJxcozuyfujkAhxlgyLxcaQ5Io6QyKgK1vxaD5MS9gXCSFyeRr%20YK%20HQRZJxYolIDpYiSPKJthLSrdOq%20VrLcKDVCCcQPiIgA)

I know, I know, now you might say to me:

Wait, I can't change my `SpecialProperty`, because this type is from third party library, I don't have control over this type.

In this case you can use next utils:

```js
type PropA = 'a'
type PropB = 'b'
type PropC = 'c'


export type SpecialProperty =
    | {

        withPropA: PropA;
    }
    | {

        withPropB: PropB;
    }
    | {

        withPropC: PropC;
    }
    
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/struggling-with-building-a-type-in-ts#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>
type StrictUnionWrapper = StrictUnion<SpecialProperty>

interface Test {
    property: StrictUnionWrapper;
}

function test(param: Test) {
    if (param.property.withPropA) {
        const prop: PropA = param.property.withPropA;
    }
    if (param.property.withPropB) {
        const prop: PropB = param.property.withPropB;
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIAKAnA9tAgvAvPA5AIZ4QwIroBCO%20ARsSFHEmtAMLV4DG9oosAHtFTJw8RggDKcTgEsCAG3JwRkHKHgb4AH3gBvXiE1H4AdxngAFkowAuZugwBudZoC%20LjTv1hDxjWcslCjsg518Nd3DtPQM-f3MrFlYQpLCjSKMDcXgAVQA7GVQ8gGlYSABnAB4AFQA%20amr4AXBYPIATcvhGgH54AGsy1AAzLvg7PNgAN1hkMOyJcGQZTnB8wryACVh5ZRqAGi6MeXl67A9R5taO%20AI8yHPexoAyJAIROXlKgCVYTmE2yoAUX4nHkAFc2rBKmsiqUKjUjicDgNIMMurUDhNpshavVxlMZmESEwFksVjC8jVTvBSctVgUilsdjN9ujiZJFnSKQB1ZAEaDKai08kMylSX4fJQzKC1AwyPItZBDAicBDVWDlUTeIzQFjSyB2YX09a8-nKMKRUBDMF5FbrMQa8AACmgbwIAFs7OrNQBKGJRGQjF1u90AOl16H1oYCiQcfu1cT%20eU18Aj0BSDmorr5YbTUZj1jSbnOgfgwZz4b1KmjCSC8fORiTKbTGegVFw2Y9lcj1YLLAoRYiBlcQA)

Personally, I use next typeguard for such kind of check:

```js
const hasProperty = <T, U extends string>(obj: T, prop: U): obj is T & Record<U, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const foo = (arg: unknown) => {
    if (hasProperty(arg, 'age')) {
        const b = arg // Record<"age", unknown>
        b.age // ok
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAFgQwgBQE4gA4FNVQJ4wC8MAPACoA0MAqjFgB5RZgAmEM0qAlmAOYB8AChAAjAFYAuGJRgZ0GKdQCUU0WJhd2ZGADIYAJSyhULEtSoBXMAGswIAO5h%20RfgCgYHmAHlxRqADo5EChgvGx-RAgvRzRMHHx-YAQAG2ThcSogjCUAbldXZKxYeiIYAG8YBF4sKQAWACYYAF88-NBIWAAzEBBSwQRUXikrWwcwJRdy908uTphBSNjsXDx%20waoAciqsDaUJsunPT3boGBFSgd4YAHprgyMQExIAIm3nyxs7Rzcjo5F-bY3O4gayHZquJquIA)