# TypeScript union type allowing values outside of type

Tags: typescript

I hope my title is clear but I'm relatively new to TS and I'm struggling with union types.

I am trying to make a generic `callApi` function which allows optional `paging` and `filters` query parameters. However, I want to make the filter options strongly typed, so for example, when calling `/api/people/`, I only want to allow `PeopleFilterQueryParams`.

This is what I've come up with until now, however, it is allowing both the `id` and the `after` filter query parameter - when it should only allow one of the two.

```
export type BookingQueryParams = {
    before?: string;
    after?: string;
}

export type PersonQueryParams = {
    id?: number;
}

export type FilterQueryParams = BookingQueryParams | PersonQueryParams;

export interface PaginationQueryParams {
    page?: number;
    size?: number;
}

export interface ApiRequestParams {
    filters?: FilterQueryParams;
    paging?: PaginationQueryParams;
}

export const callApi = (url: string, params?: ApiRequestParams) => {
    return ``;
}

callApi('/people', {
    filters: {
        id: 123,
        after: '',
    }
})
```

I have a TS playground link here demonstrating my problem:
[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCEIGsCWA7AcwEUBXYKRABQEMpqBbAZzgF44BvAKDh7gCNgAM2jAA-AC44jGFHwEA3N17VBMchKky5igL6dOoSLATJUlcowh5S5KrQbM2XXnBwATDXhL0BUXfsNoeCQUOAAxHAAbNSgbCho6JlZ0TFxCOLtE5gAfOHMoS2syePsmRQNwINc8GMFqAGMzagJ8ahgcKwyEhw4lHjBmsUkvH3JFF0YcAC8huBHffwqjeHxahtQAQTAcACVgAEcyaW6k515BKJjGDQjo8i7SxnHeAZbCDRo3to6i2xOnzh6JZVepWaRwerUSKRLY4ZIAChIUEikmkskIABo4AMshpYXtDsBjo8AJSsAB8vRcUGAMCReDgAANGYtIdDYfCAOQAehQEDAkWAnKxZx4FzuBUkopcrjckgAjAAmADMGL6MpUMUknOF6r0OhJQA)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that's because of some bug with nested unions. Can't find the github issue.

However, there is a workaround.

```js
export type BookingQueryParams = {
    before?: string;
    after?: string;
}

export type PersonQueryParams = {
    id?: number;
}

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = 
    T extends any 
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/struggling-with-building-a-type-in-ts#answer-65805753
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

export type FilterQueryParams = StrictUnion<BookingQueryParams | PersonQueryParams>;

export interface PaginationQueryParams {
    page?: number;
    size?: number;
}

export interface ApiRequestParams {
    filters?: FilterQueryParams;
    paging?: PaginationQueryParams;
}

export const callApi = (url: string, params?: ApiRequestParams) => {
    return ``;
}

callApi('/people', {
    filters: {
        id: 123,
        after: '', // error
    }
})
```

[Credits goes to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/struggling-with-building-a-type-in-ts#answer-65805753) Titian Cernicova-Dragomir

You just need to make union much more stricted

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20863

Comment: Interesting reading material. This seems to solve the problem. Thanks for the swift response!

Comment: @nbokmans btw, I have a blog https://catchts.com/ , I made several article about working with union. I'd willing to bet that you will find some interesting examples. All my articles are based on StackOverflow questions/answers