# Typescript - How Multiple Type situation in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

## Example Code:

```
type PropsType = {top: number} | {bottom: number}

// A funtion that make something run at one direction by distance.
function run(props: PropsType) {
...
}
```

## Expected:

`run({top: 100})` or `run({bottom: 100})`

not `run({top: 100, bottom: 100})` (which is the current)

not trigger suggtion have both props: [image]

## Question:

So, how to limit the type with different situation, I don't want the props accept `top` and `bottom` at same time.

Comment: I've searched everywhere but no good solution, maybe I should compromise by redesign the props : {direction: 'top' | 'bottom', distance: number}

Answer (score 2):

You can use "never" keyword like this:

```
type PropsType = {top: number, bottom?: never} | {top?: never, bottom: number}

// A funtion that make something run at one direction by distance.
function run(props: PropsType) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your union more stricted:

```js
type PropsType = { top: number } | { bottom: number }

// credits goes to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/struggling-with-building-a-type-in-ts#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
  T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

// A funtion that make something run at one direction by distance.
function run(props: StrictUnion<PropsType>) {

}

run({ top: 100, bottom: 100 }) // error
run({ top: 100 }) // ok
run({ bottom: 100 }) // ok
```

If this line :

```js
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZwCrmgXigbysJALigDsBXAWwCMI4oBfKAH1yioWAIuPOtoYCwAKGEB6UVADGcCABMAlsGRQA5ggjKCUVIvkBDElADCtEvMkIAbnoC0AETh61FeXDGiAFpxSFxyYHqSANZWtABmADYIAO4AdBYUogCOZBrA8ggkyKIAbACsABwADHk5RUWi-nBkKioR8iQqNtGKHjZUZPIRCo02tqCQNg02SgDEBsjRtDb5xXkA7HkAzMID0ACqZpkA0hAgyAA8qAB8UNioUBAAHsAQJLLKFwD8UEF7CGHaUDwQlrQA3KsMFAAMrAODmYCbDIkAASEAikDgRwANNoAIIRCKnTDCKBfa63e7KAwgPFQF4XABksD0cHSegiBwAShALHBZAcAKJXSQRMiyCAHaE7PaHVCY7Fot4gD7aY5oki-WjHU4-P5wQEiIRrUHgyEikhHHF6iGSKFbOEIpGo%20XCdxQdFQMJkEjpTL4Dx6YBQCh6N5QZAICgQYAeBoqKDVQzeqCZaAKGTmmFsEBQBT%20AySCCxYQukjJj3RgAUYEQPlNBstB3gSDQGGOAEpcPahPRWyW8AQwMQAIzlNHsTjBvvlBjN8SXOCINxCTv4IhQftFcdQScIILCedDrijlf0CcSDdAA)

is not clear for you, please refer to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

> When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type.
> If we plug a union type into ToArray, then the conditional type will be applied to each member of that union.

Comment: Thanks, this solution is pretty, but trigger suggestion still have both props.

Comment: @Yokiijay sorry, I did not understand you. What do you mean: trigger sugestion? I added playground link, it is not possible to have both props

Comment: I posted a screenshot above, it's vscode `trigger suggest`.

Comment: but you are unable to set bottom

Comment: Yeah, but Type hints are also very important, providing documentation capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

What about optional parameter?

```
type PropsType = {top?: number, bottom?: number}
```

Usage will be:

```
run({top: 100});
run({bottom: 100});
```

Comment: run({ top: 100, bottom: 100 }) // will not throw any error

Comment: Yes, it will not. I think the best solution will be to use `never` where the purpose of `never` type exactly matches will the user's requirement but optional params are more cleaner for me.