# Prevent props using propTypes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I have a button that can have multiple props:

```
interface buttonProps {
    secondary?: boolean;
    tertiary?: boolean;
    width?: number;
    children?: any;
    icon?: string;
}
```

If button has `icon` passed with no `children`, I want to prevent adding props: `secondary`, `tertiary` and `width`. Is it possible to do with TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

**UPDATE**

```js
type OnlyIcon = {
    icon: string;
}
type IconWithChildren = {
    secondary: boolean;
    tertiary: boolean;
    width: number;
    children: any;
    icon: string;
}

// credits goes to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/struggling-with-building-a-type-in-ts#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type ButtonProps = StrictUnion<IconWithChildren | OnlyIcon>;

const props: ButtonProps = {
    icon: 'd',
} // ok

const props2: ButtonProps = {
    icon: 'd',
    secondary: true
} // error

const props3: ButtonProps = {
    icon: 'd',
    secondary: true,
    tertiary:false,
} // error

const props4: ButtonProps = {
    icon: 'd',
    secondary: true,
    tertiary:false,
    width:1
} // error

const props5: ButtonProps = {
    icon: 'd',
    secondary: true,
    tertiary:false,
    width:1,
    children:{}
} // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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%20e2Ksruvr7Sb7fKXeeAeK4hOK4SUHgXDtnGdpAA)

Docs: [Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html), [Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), [DIstributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

Comment: Won't it accept all props like this? I need that if button has `icon` prop passed, any other props added should be counted as error until `children` are added as well.

Comment: also, can you add link to info source?