# Typescript keyof of nested object

Tags: typescript

I am having the following type

```
export type Groups = {
  group1: {
    prop1?: string;
    prop2?: number;
  };
  group2: {
    prop3?: string;
  };
};
```

I want to define another type to be built based on that group

```
type AllGroups = {
  groupName: keyof Groups;
  prop: keyof Groups[keyof Groups];
  values: string[];
}[];
```

Then i define the object

```
const allGroups: AllGroups = [
  {
    groupName: 'group1',
    prop: 'prop1',
    values: ['a']
  },
];
```

Problem is typescript is complaining on the `prop` field. The `groupName` field is fine.

```
TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. The expected type comes from property 'prop''
```

I am not sure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider next example:

```js
type Result = {
    prop1?: string | undefined;
    prop2?: number | undefined;
} | {
    prop3?: string | undefined;
}

type Keys = keyof Result // never
```

There is no common keys in above union, hence TS is unable to figure out which keys it should return to you. That's why you are receiving an error.

To handle such kind of unions, you can use @Shivam Singla 's way or this generic way:

```js
// credits goes to Titian Cernicova-Dragomir 
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>
```

So, instead of writing:

```js
keyof Groups[keyof Groups];
```

You can write:

```js
keyof StrictUnion<Groups[keyof Groups]>
```

Here is my full solution:

```js
export type Groups = {
    group1: {
        prop1?: string;
        prop2?: number;
    };
    group2: {
        prop3?: string;
    };
};

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>


interface AllGroups {
    groupName: keyof Groups;
    prop: keyof StrictUnion<Groups[keyof Groups]>;
    values: string[];
};

const allGroups = <T extends AllGroups, U extends {
    0: ReadonlyArray<T>,
}[
    T['groupName'] extends keyof Groups
    ? T['prop'] extends keyof Groups[T['groupName']]
    ? 0 : never : never]>(arr: ReadonlyArray<T> & U) => arr;

const result = allGroups(
    [{
        groupName: 'group1',
        prop: 'prop2',
        values: ['a']
    },
    {
        groupName: 'group1',
        prop: 'prop1',
        values: ['a']
    }]) // ok

const result2 = allGroups(
    [{
        groupName: 'group1',
        prop: 'prop2',
        values: ['a']
    },
    {
        groupName: 'group1',
        prop: 'prop3', // expected error
        values: ['a']
    }]) // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiUIFcwGc4C8cA3gFBwVwDmmOAjAFwnmWtiZh0D8TuMUASwB2VANwtWFdhDAAmHnCFYAtgCNgUcawC%20WyjWxymZSZWlgAzAr6CReirtKPSSFHACqQgRCEBpYIi4ADwAKgB8hHAhcKAwwEIAJvjRXHAA1gEQAGZRcExCwABuGuKuqADK-AIAxjCe3kIAEsAANihQoQA0UQCCLS0RBBK5sfFJcACGQojDqdEAZHAAChOwAhMtQQBKwNXQCUEAoiDVLVgJwEH1Pv6BoX0D3RmI2VFh3QXFUGER%20UUlpBcyAqVVq1yEoUGcEqgjBXh8zTaGi6b0BpGEcSgWQm1VQDwwhnwJn0tDAADkJspgExnq8CThcPY4OYaZkcjCanV4RD6XgANq0nK83AAXTCTMKGywwFwvCqIj5IvEzj2Qj4k36wsioRiIDiiXw%20NJuG67l1%20vGxIoAAYmDsJgkfC1ED0oFAJohIZ0nHzhiE%20QByAw4ClUgMi81jfCC9DG2ZRQPmcORg3pNmxwl8-1B0mh4DhkXx615RT-KAlz4aMUAClWUDtwAdTpdbo9kLgi3cAEpCBE6%20JSKr1VAZVgWvAiBsWsLq8M%20VbJMHyZTqXAc4Y6AHvaYpBwmAHzLIt8NWJKzjKmIGJuHhtpt5QF6wl3n90vN-fTCy1%20Z3yfKGfpVlOArxvHQRR7AB6CC4AgNJASHeAR1wMcYFkSIpxnOdHxJQwXzXN9jx3Zk92-Dgjw-SQAIvYCA2vQsdAo7CKGfFdX1JX8iK-A8OAsLc4Cg3UUFqYAEhiN1oD-CgqKAkD6MobRwP46DYKAA)

Drawbacks: here you should use function which literally do nothing except type infering.

I assume it will be optimized by V8 engine.

You can also use [closure webpack plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/closure-webpack-plugin/) to get rid of function call.

However, I'm voting for @Shivam Singla 's solution because there is no function overhead.

I just published this solution to give you some alternative way.

This type is a bit complicated:

```js
const allGroups = <T extends AllGroups, U extends {
    0: ReadonlyArray<T>,
}[
    T['groupName'] extends keyof Groups
    ? T['prop'] extends keyof Groups[T['groupName']]
    ? 0 : never : never]>(arr: ReadonlyArray<T> & U) => arr;
```

But this is the way how I do my validation of function arguments.

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

Consirder following code-

```
export type Groups = {
  group1: {
    prop1?: string;
    prop2?: number;
  };
  group2: {
    prop3?: string;
  };
};

type Z = Groups[keyof Groups]

type X = keyof Z
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=17#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiUIFcwGc4C8cA3gFBxwDmmOAjAFwnkVxiZi0D8juMUAlgDtKAbmYU2EMACZucQVgC2AI2BQxFAL4aqNGYzItW7AMxzeA4Tu2kbpJCjgAtQuj24A2gGtgiCADM3bDwAXVJ7ZFQADVcfP0CnIA)

The type `Z` is a union of all possible types from `Groups`. The `keyof` of a union type returns `never`. That's why type of `prop` in `AllGroups` was `never`

### Solution

We create a union type from `Groups` and then use them as [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

```js
export type Groups = {
  group1: {
    prop1?: string;
    prop2?: number;
  };
  group2: {
    prop3?: string;
  };
};

type AllGroups = {
  [K in keyof Groups]: {
    groupName: K
    prop: keyof Groups[K]
    values: string[]
  }
}[keyof Groups][]

const allGroups: AllGroups = [
  {
    groupName: 'group1',
    prop: 'prop2',
    values: ['a']
  },
  {
    groupName: 'group1',
    prop: 'prop3', // error expected
    values: ['a']
  },
  {
    groupName: 'group2',
    prop: 'prop3',
    values: ['a']
  },
  {
    groupName: 'group2',
    prop: 'prop1', // error expected
    values: ['a']
  },
];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=40&pc=3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDiUIFcwGc4C8cA3gFBxwDmmOAjAFwnkVxiZi0D8juMUAlgDtKAbmYU2EMACZucQVgC2AI2BQxFAL4aqNGYzItW7AMxzeA4Tu2kbpJCjgBBADYuM2PISYUA2gGk4ITgAa2BECAAzdD1cAF0DcV1PADkAQ0VgRn8kyTBGMIjojxxcALikgDc0lyxgXB4+IUpfCq1bX0KomM941tJSAGMIQV44GvdYxldJ3u9fZkMWalSMrLgAchW6DYAaXPZGDbzpPaqauoa4Xw20jba4TX2KJYptsHTMo-faM6M8o55Ex7OAAelBcDUmCgkPAwEGMGAABNzrV6owbncHk9Fkl3p91ls9KdniwAZsgX8WNU0VdMfdmDiXni9ATvsSqRJDhT2L9dmCIVDoLCUAjkajLhjbgytPs4iIgA)

Comment: Unfortunately, if you will `groupName: 'group2' will allow `prop1`

Comment: @captain-yossarian Oh, I misunderstood the problem. My bad. Fixing it!

Comment: anyway, your solution is good. In order to infer correctly `groupName` property, I believe we need wrap it in function

Comment: Or, we can have discriminated union types.

Comment: Correct, if you will define types for each group, it should be ok