# Property X doesn't exist on type, when actually exists

Tags: typescript, types, compiler-errors

when I define (in typescript) custom type, it correctly whisper, when i assign to variable of that type. For example in my code below, when I define variable "error", typescript correctly whisper, that I must add "message" or "code" (as I defined type IErrorType, that it must have at least one of that). But when I use it in function parameter, like in my "printError()", that in function it gives me error:
"Property 'message' does not exist on type 'IErrorType'."

But it exists! How can I solve it? I need type in which you must type at least one property from one interface or from another (or from both)...My code is minimal working example, so you can run it...

```
type IErrorType = IErrorCode | IErrorMessage;

interface IErrorCode {
    code: number;
}

interface IErrorMessage {
    message: string;
}

let error: IErrorType = {
    code: 5
}
let error2: IErrorType = {
    message: "Error!!!"
}
let error3: IErrorType = {
    message: "Error 7!!!",
    code: 7
}

function printError(err: IErrorType){
    if(err && err.message){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}

printError(error3);
printError(error2);
printError(error);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since not all of the types in the union have a `.message` property on them, typescript will not let you access `err.message`. Instead, you should use the `in` operator to check whether message exists before you try to access it:

```
function printError(err: IErrorType) {
  if ('message' in err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgogJwQewQFXNAvLRKEDCyAJtAD65KoCyEAznQIYDmEA3ALABQ3AlgHbAICAGaMAxtHhVCJaAG9uUZVHFyAXFH4BXALYAjYZy4Bfbn0HCxkyvloMWCpSt30mrTXWAIBzY2Z4uABsIYChhfE1pfAxIKBxFLhVVDSgAVm4AkLCI1AAmKLxUWOwoROTXBw8oACIihABCJprM7mzwmQBmQpkS%20LLnZUr3CE06mSgAdiaGmoAaQZTSTUnWwJFtfnFgXmR%20KDAfQXqACgiemMwASgGkqF4RKBOAcmHHZ-v9iJvylTV%20OjIEIAOiCyGYZyQwLerCuxmUAQC3EOAmAp1yCE6cORRzRMkh%20Dy2K4KOO%20IxcKAA)

---

EDIT: if you want to change your types, here are some options. If you want to be able to use err.message without checking what it is, then `.message` needs to be on the type.

The following types would require that you either have `code`, or you have `message`, but not both.

```
type IErrorType = IErrorCode | IErrorMessage;

interface IErrorCode {
    code: number;
    message?: never;
}

interface IErrorMessage {
    code?: never;
    message: string;
}

function printError(err: IErrorType) {
  console.log(err.message);
}
```

If you want to allow both, then take one of the `never`s and turn it into the actual type (while still keeping it optional):

```
type IErrorType = IErrorCode | IErrorMessage;

interface IErrorCode {
    code: number;
    message?: never;
}

interface IErrorMessage {
    code?: number; // <---- now an optional number
    message: string;
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works. But is there way to print err.message without that "in" check? Never mind if I must edit my types definition... But I want to have condition, that any of properties (code/message) must be specified. And the in function if that property will not specified it should just print undefined...Is it possible to do that?

Comment: I've added some options that would allow you to skip the check, because the properties are now part of the type (albeit optional properties)

Answer (score 0):

There is alternative solution:

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
  T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type IErrorType = StrictUnion<IErrorCode | IErrorMessage> | IErrorMessage & IErrorMessage;

interface IErrorCode {
  code: number;
}

interface IErrorMessage {
  message: string;
}

let error: IErrorType = {
  code: 5
}
let error2: IErrorType = {
  message: "Error!!!"
}
let error3: IErrorType = {
  message: "Error 7!!!",
  code: 7
}

function printError(err: IErrorType) {
  if (err && err.message) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
}

printError(error3);
printError(error2);
printError(error);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIFUB2BLA9og0tcBnAPACoB8sAvLAbNAB6jSIAmOFsA-LANbaoBmLAXLETQAbtABOAbjBQ4AZVDjkAY1BI0iABLQANjHGEANBQCCOnSVLBYLGnUbMAhonDW2LAGSwACo-GhkRx08ACVoZVRxBjwAUWplHQBXBmg8dXQsXEIzC2MucF4KImNhMXEiEkFSiWkZGFgFJVV0xEJLBsUVNRR0bT0JIyKQCHqASRjxcUiCWTIOpu6NPHHJyIBhVBTYAB9YFanxAFloHBxHAHNoEl39yOPTi7gvW6OTs8va5EQ6cR5HZTgLw2WwA3m4IikqokALYAIxqwAAviAvj8-gC9hMDvd3nAwTZoW9HoIcJ1EOdpMjgDpoKAqKtxIIXjN6uR8bAIdBBABWJHU2n0g4AJiZWOmszZbkJD0uggARGLxABCFVyvk0ukSA4AZlFDJZcElBKJstgCoZsAA7CqlXLDODNlyrXzgDxEohVBpYJAlN9FQAKLV6g4GgCUsHZyD4gcmsA8Xi1ADppbjw%20ybBFEDhUDTEzpUOcY%20JkyboKHpDZkVSfaiA1rItry8Aa36GUXIkKmy3QHWGeWgA)