# Optional generic type and corresponding parameters for TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics

I have the following React functional component that takes generic parameters:

```
type Props<T, S> = {
  data: T[]
  additionalData: S
}

function Component<T, S = void>({
 ....
```

You can use it as follow:

```
<Component<Bike, BikeShed> data={bikes} additionalData={bikeShed} />
```

Since the second generic parameter is optional, you have to use it as follows:

```
<Component<Car> data={cars} additionalData={undefined} />
```

Now here is the question. Is there a way to omit the `additionalData={undefined}` because it is clearly not being used here.

What I tried is this:

```
type Props<T, S = void> = {
  data: T[]
  additionalData?: S
}
```

But it effectively changes `S` to `S | undefined`, not an ideal situation!

Can I set up my `Props` in a way where I don't have to specify its relating properties when the optional generic parameter is `void`?

Answer (score 0):

Yep - you can check if S is void and if so evaluate to a type without additionalData using conditional types:

```js
type BaseProps<T> = { data: T[] };
type PropsWithAdditionalData<T, S> = BaseProps<T> & { additionalData: S };
type Props<T, S = void> = S extends void ? BaseProps<T> : PropsWithAdditionalData<T, S>;

const hasAdditionalData = <T, S>(props: BaseProps<T> | PropsWithAdditionalData<T, S>): props is PropsWithAdditionalData<T, S> => {
  return !!(props as unknown as PropsWithAdditionalData<T, S>).additionalData;
}

function Component<T, S = void>(props: Props<T, S>) {
  if (hasAdditionalData<T, S>(props)) {
    return <div>{props.additionalData}</div>;
  }
  return <div>{props.data}</div>;
}

type Car = { id: number };
const cars = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];

const noAdditionalData = <Component<Car> data={cars} />;
const additionalData = <Component<Car, number> data={cars} additionalData={1} />;
```

`S extends void` checks if the type S is assignable to void (which is is in the default case) and if so returns just `{ data: T[] }`.

Comment: this makes it not possible to access to `additionalData` if you assign `Props` as the component props type like `function Comp<T, S = void>(props: Props<T, S>) { ... }`

Comment: Yes - because TS can't tell which of the two types you'll have so it safely evaluates to the intersection. You can use type guards to tell TS which type you have

Answer (score 0):

Your `Props` type should be strict union type.

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

// credits goes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Props<T, S> = StrictUnion<{
    data: T[]
} | {
    data: T[]
    additionalData: S
}>

type Bike = {
    color: string
}

type BikeShed = {
    model: string
}
const Foo = <T, S = void>(props: Props<T, S>) => {
    const { additionalData } = props // ok, but may be undefined
    const { data } = props; // ok

    return null
}

const bikes: Bike[] = []
const bikeShed = { model: '' }

const component = <Foo<Bike, BikeShed> data={[]} />
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDMwCeYScAqgHbAIfANJJ2AZwA8AFQB8cALxxpcJAA8YSPgBNxyuAH44AazERy%20gFxw%20SAG5IoAbjaduAZRhRgGfoL4AEkgANlxQMtjSAILBwfIKzHBJ%20uqaOnoofOyJyUYqAGRwAAoosMAowZLIaNDakgCiamjBAK7aSJJ%20QqISMjFx2Kbs5sqy2LYOULLy1hOOLq5ccJ7evgJCMvHLXj4wXYEhYRGjrBxLRVRgUtLY7lsru-uSODlJ2igwKNbSANoAuswyAAfXCvODvT7ff5glDabTAGD%20CoAEQ%20X2WgNkpzccAAQsBTIpQck4DVgtBrOIdnwAOaA7FLfGmdwACyQ2iJLxJIAg7WClOpdJIzBqfCpBAgECJx3cRLsEGA2lkAAowJdxNYLhArjLZABKRTyLnJUXivCw%20GIoQotGkIlq7V6AD0TrgEGM2AARi14CAUOw4J7uC0dEhyMBbNowab4HgISg7UoHVcnHAXW7jKwSQwYC0oHwbC1YvSRUJxZ6CUgNXjK-8idCY4HK6z2Zy4Dy%20dZaLRSKxGzVwEItPAlJJ8JLJEykNgpy2leC0QocP8yE7ZEA)

More information about handling union props in React You can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/unions)

**UPDATE**

You can also try [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type WithoutAdditional<T> = {
    data: T[]
}
type WithAdditional<T, S> = {
    data: T[]
    additionalData: S
}

type Props<T, S> =
    | WithAdditional<T, S>
    | WithoutAdditional<T>

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop): obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)

const withAdditional = <T, S>(obj: Props<T, S>): obj is WithAdditional<T, S> => hasProperty(obj, 'additionalData')

type Bike = {
    color: string
}

type BikeShed = {
    model: string
}
const Foo = <T, S = void>(props: Props<T, S>) => {
    if (withAdditional(props)) {
        const x = props; // WIthAdditional

    } else {
        const y = props; // WIthoutAdditional
    }

    return null
}

const bikes: Bike[] = []
const bikeShed = { model: '' }

const component = <Foo<Bike, BikeShed> data={[]} />
```

[Playground 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDMwCeYScA6sDAAsIAVxgBBACYT%20wCADsUAGwA8AFQB8cALy5mcfXAkoYKAFxxVAbQC6zEm07c%20gydJiyFK1dgDKmnTh6BkYm5la2BnAoUjLySgAixmZwPnasHFxwAApUYADOar7%20QfoAPrz8Aq6xnoUp6iVw5c5CotXucV4NzGjyefACKHk5EFyw7NpwygDyAEYAVtgjYHBIAB4wSHISeXD9UMByAObqABQQC%20Zzi3BguebLAJTmF-NwwLvXcABkiEi9UAkymW2GEcgA1nIIAB3OT%20BqRa7-GAAOjuEBgGMcKMGeWmsOWSHGKLQSkU5wW2HRYEerF6cn6cGhlXaHiUkzqfgp8weuQK3nqzzgr3euxarM6nPhcFxhPG3OwtGibjZikSJlotIcmQAQsBwdwAo1eopoOZ9ocjmltdw9QafAIkBJJoFIiAIBIkIpzTADsc0vTGfgIBAOQKfJMAG4QYASM7UvK80b8oqPbSaV0GYDkOCnZkuGIdTynBOPNOZyL6QPwNaTBMAbjgAHom7wAJIFlWdViRMhevLcCuV6twCY6BvN1s8DutcSF1WNeyNBgwYRQORwOTCRSKa0j2b6pCJuB2pA2SY2Hp9eAH%202O50BODuz3eui0Uh069wXrgeRbeA6MowYQMop7YKeDpOpoIQoFoOA2GQTbqEAA)

Comment: What are the differences between using this and making `additionalData` optional (`additionalData?: S`)?

Comment: Also, I actually have 2 generic types that can be optional.. how do I do this without blowing up the number of permutations of the types?

Comment: Just make it all optional and use typeguards to handle it

Comment: @Owl above approach helps if you already have a union type and you have to deal with it. But in general, you are right, I made an update

Answer (score 0):

I was just stuck trying to figure out a similar, but not quite equivalent situation. Just going to put this here in case anyone else finds themselves on this thread stuck on the same thing.

I have a function that takes either one or two arguments depending on the type of the first argument. Specifically, it's a function that opens one of many modals, but some modals take data that they use to render, while others don't need any data. I want it to be typed so that if the modal being opened requires data, TS will validate that the data is being passed in and that it's the correct type. I struggled with this for a while but finally figured out this solution.

```js
type ModalID = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e';

interface ModalData = {
 a: void;
 b: void;
 c: SomeData;
 d: SomeOtherData;
 e: void;
}

type OpenModal = <ID extends ModalID>(
  ...args: ModalData[ID] extends void 
    ? [id: ID] 
    : [id: ID, data: ModalData[ID]]
) => void;
```