# Typescript: Scoping multiple return types

Tags: typescript, generics, types, polymorphism

I have a function that returns a HandleAnswer.

```
 export type HandleAnswer =
        | {
            mint_nft: {
                token_id: string;
            };
        }
        | {
            batch_mint_nft: {
                token_ids: string[];
            };
        }
        | {
            set_public_metadata: {
                status: ResponseStatus;
            };
        }
```

I have a similar type for a parameter. If I start adding the parameter it 'scopes' to the correct type. So if I enter `functionA({mint_nft:{` it autocompletes to token_id of type string.
If I do the same for the result it seems to only pick up the first type ever:

```
const test:HandleAnswer = functionA(...)
test.batch_mint_nft <-- this will rise a compiler warning that HandleAnswer does not contain batch_mint_nft, only mint_nft.
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: It should complain about all them, including `mint_nft`, because TS doesn't know which of the 3 is returned by the function. Will the function return the same type it receives? If so you can use generics.

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties
Either use StrictUnion ot add sharable property to each union

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3p6w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, with no unrelated errors or problems.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.