# Use one interface out of many for params in function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function like this:

```
interface Interface1 {
    one: string
}
interface Interface2 {
    two: string
}
interface Interface3 {
    three: string
}
type ManyInterfacesInOneType = Interface1 | Interface2 | Interface3;

function bla(param1: ManyInterfacesInOneType) {

}
```

When I try to use the function like this and I call the function like `bla({...})`, it lets me put variables from all the interfaces, but I want the function to be limited to one out of many. **So I don't want this to happen:**

```
bla({one: '', two: '', three: ''});
```

I also tried doing:

```
function bla<T extends object>(param1: T) {

}
```

But this doesn't make the generic type required, so it doesn't even really help.

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Comment: @FZs it's just multiple interfaces declared in one type as I've said and I wrote the problem that I am having as well, what different code or explanation do you need exactly?

Comment: @FZs I have added more code and an example, hope it's a bit more explanatory now

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Thanks for that, have my vote. However, I don't think I know the solution to this.

Comment: @FZs thanks for improving the question anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to do with small helper:

```js
interface Interface1 {
    one: string
}
interface Interface2 {
    two: string
}
interface Interface3 {
    three: string
}
type Union = Interface1 | Interface2 | Interface3;

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>


function bla<T extends Union,>(param1: StrictUnion<Union>) {

}

bla({ one: 'one' }) // ok
bla({one:'one', two:'two'}) // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJBGZBvAKGWOQHsQIAuZAZzClAHMCBfA0SWRFdTrCAEz4iJMAHdS1OgxDM2HTNzQYuSAMzCSyMAAsoEKrXpNWBMAE8ADigCqIYOWQBeZX264APq8VIhX3j4QagDcBAQA9OHICPoAJsBgNMiMpBBJYKTIOmBgljSUkXSIANakAG6YADakYgB0CKQAtuEAjgCuaWAOIDThAGwArAAcAAwDfSMj4RbWALRt9uSzIKRgswg6EAjFTLMwpFCzEAAeSDQ0s5ZQpNZQXWkAxHA9YtCzg6MDAOwDamZWtkWIAA0hBzDQADwAFQAfM5kFDkCdICBYklEQB%20ZDFMGkGAI5DUCgVKChGYoADKxgQYDs3QAEhBKrdoQAaBEAQUqlThThExERyIgqKSz3M-OQWMRADJkAAFOB3YBwSoQgBKWwOsQhAFFTpU2rEIBC6eRQeDoVyeeyceY8QiYezidAYXCiRASaF-tZkFSGDTTSBobzfdTaUDGczoGyHWECDAFjTusgAEaVODQpHHFFo5CB1kwgAUlkVcEa2GofuAAaBJqBMIAlMJTAQ03BC3gyBRqABycgQHvIFhNyJkYqt9Md-uUPsUHvs8SSHuLnvD5Cj6DXKBAA)

[Here](https://catchts.com/), in my blog, you can find more examples of utility types which are useful in practice, because all of them are taken from here (stackoverflow)

Comment: Now this is some damn magic, thanks a lot!