# TypeScript union types - error only on function invocation

Tags: typescript

I've stumbled upon a weird behavior when using union types in TypeScript. When passing a reference of a function, without invoking it, there is no type error:

```
type A = boolean;
type B = string;
type C = number; 
type BC = B | C; 

interface Props { onChange(expr: A | BC): void } 

const SomeFunction = (_props: Props) => {}
const handler = (el: A | B) => { console.log(el) } 
 
SomeFunction({onChange: handler}) // no error here 
 
SomeFunction({onChange: e => handler(e)}) // <- TS Error: Argument of type 'boolean | BC' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | boolean'.
```

The only explanation I could find is [improved behavior for calling union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) in TypeScript 3.3.

I'm curious about the reasons why there is no error when calling `SomeFunction({onChange: handler})` - Is it because there is an overlap between union types?

[link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UBGB7FAbCBDAdgbgChRIoAhBKAZ2ACcBLHAc0OOgGEKcBXAWyQhp4oRcNFIdE5AD5Q2QggQbABAMywBjaAAUaKMJSgBvKChxsAFrkYQAFBAAeYGgC5YUGeICUrgG4o6ACZQAL7CBOqm1FAAyig8EABiXDjqwHSmFDYA+k56lK46eZ4IAHxGweGRwFCWOAGYNJkQ6K5wHsXwZcYROJQYEAB06CiMdujFoQTCsfFJKWmmNoamFlYQrrX1AsHFAPS7UDgoUAK6jeYC0FMEM4nJqek4Syu11q7QnTW4WzR2njtQfZQAA8AFooAAVaJQACiNDOrRojF4EBw1RQKigrCgAHJUP1cO4yGwcVA6AYjtUsJRKHRGDgsEhMFjjmAsDQsPFlI0MVjRLjqPQmET8ZhcDiBgQgA)

Comment: I don't see any union types being called here: in the call `f(x)`, `x` is a union, but `f` is not.  Instead this is the difference between contravariant function arguments (safe, when `--strictFunctionTypes` is turned on) and bivariant *method* arguments (unsafe no matter what compiler option you use). If you write the `onChange` definition with function syntax instead of method syntax you will [see the error in both places](https://tsplay.dev/mLlaAm), for good reason as shown.  Does that answer your question? If so I can write up a post; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, perhaps my terminology wasn't the best when formulating the question.  That's a good catch with onChange definition, thank you! I still try understand why there is no error with a method definition 

Comment: Method parameters are treated as *bivariant*, see [this q/a](//stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for explanation of what that means.  There's [this FAQ entry](//github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) explaining why they allow it. With `--strictFunctionTypes` this is made safe for non-method functions, but they left it in place for methods because otherwise a bunch of built-in things like `Array` would become nearly unusable.  I can go into more detail if I write up an answer, which I can do unless I'm missing something about your question.

Comment: No, I think that's it - just trying to understand why there is no error when using method definition in the above snippet. If you could write up a detail answer I think it could be also helpful for other people and I certainly would appreciate it as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `handler` is a non-method function, while `onChange` was declared in `Props` to be a method.  And when you have [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes) enabled (which is part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler functionality](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict)), parameters of non-method functions are checked more strictly.

In order to be type safe, a function's parameters should be checked *contravariantly*, which is described in [this q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218), but briefly, a function parameter can be safely *narrowed* but not *widened*. Since `Expr | Primitive` is wider than `Expr | StringOrBool`, it is not safe to treat `handler` as an `onChange`, as shown here when you add some functionality:

```
const SomeFunction = (_props: Props) => { _props.onChange(3) }

const handler = (el: Expr | StringOrBool) => {
    if ((typeof el !== "boolean") && (typeof el !== "object")) {
        console.log(el.toUpperCase()); // has to be a string, right?
    }
    console.log(el)
}

SomeFunction({ onChange: handler }) // runtime error: el.toUpperCase is not a function
```

The `handler` function assumes that a non-boolean non-object parameter must be a string, but `SomeFunction` calls `_props.onChange()` with a *number*.  Oops!

So at this point it should be clear that, if all we care about is type safety, there should be an error in *both* invocations of `SomeFunction`.  Indeed, if we rewrite `Props` to use non-method syntax for `onChange`:

```
interface Props {
    onChange: (expr: Expr | Primitive) => void // call expression, not method
}
```

then we do see both errors:

```
SomeFunction({ onChange: handler }) // error! 
SomeFunction({ onChange: e => handler(e) }) // error!
```

---

But methods (and indeed all functions without `--strictFunctionTypes` enabled) allow both the safe narrowing (contravariance) and the unsafe widening (covariance).  That is, method parameters are checked *bivariantly*.  Why?  Well, it turns out that even though this is unsafe, it's quite useful.  You can read [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant) or [this doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) for details, but in short, it enables some common coding practices (like event handling).  People *like* treating a `Dog[]` as if it were an `Animal[]`, even though it is technically unsafe.  If methods were treated safely, then the existence of the `push()` method of `Animal[]` would prevent anyone from using a `Dog[]` as an `Animal[]`. See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60905518/2887218) for more information.

Because we have both method syntax and arrow function syntax available to us, we can sort of have it both ways if we want; anytime you care about type safety of function parameters, stay away from method syntax.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHmATlAvFA3lCDEC4rCICu0AvgNwBQokUAyoQJYB2A5gPKIBCA9jwDaooAZyZsoAHygAjPvwgBDZlRrQAckQC2Q5lukREK8NAAKiRpsbBGAN2hoG5tp14DJUDZsreWwAwDMFAGNTRB4wYQxKKBioHmYAYQALJVYIfAAKbCR8eCR3MwsrWwgASlQAPigbHkYAEygAekaoAB4AWnaoIJS2aGAeKH8iZiDreJEQZmAFOCglBuYeYChNCGAkngbhKZm4SlJvIPjReh41gDERscYJtAyAfSRw4XwzF-KUKswnsIiAOniyVSEAyAGZyodKMdmKdenV5Mh7hB+LkcO5HCwONw5J9vtFYox-FAMhlVDxiSioABCFBoABEsgEimY9PKADJ2STyZTBLSGTxpAArCBjNnldAE2KxGHCZn-fg8VhZfj-AYAVTAkEQCQUwlBpVK5CaLRSkQGMmgChEYlYABooOZWElgAB+KVQQ7S2XyxXKlGlA7eOjnCBXUbjZgZTBA3ppfDwxGe8rNLCIMKIalQSghy7XSPRuKJOPpLCVKCJgxZSEploGDPUyip4jTCzQes8PBYVUarUGXX6qCMSJLFbW4YR27MIA)

Answer (score 1):

one solution for this would be to use strict unions:

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>>
  : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>;
```

Then if you declare the `Primitive` type as `type Primitive = StrictUnion<StringOrBool | Num>` you would get the correct error for both of them. I think this is one workaround for the problem that @jcalz mentioned in the comments that the `method syntax declaration` is not supported this way. StrictUnion also understands the method syntax. This implementation is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524597/use-one-interface-out-of-many-for-params-in-function).