# Distinguish between two types joined with or in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

When I have a type that can be something or undefined, I can easily use an if statement to check it contains something:

```
type MaybeString = string | undefined;

function useMaybeString(arg: MaybeString) {
    if (arg !== undefined) {
        printString(arg);
    }
}

function printString(arg: string) {
    console.log(arg)
}
```

But this example where my type can be one of two posibilities doesn't work:

```
type Foo = {foo: string};
type Bar = {bar: string};

type FooOrBar = Foo | Bar;

function useFooOrBar(arg: FooOrBar) {
    if (arg.foo !== undefined) {
        console.log(arg.foo);
    } else {
        console.log(arg.bar);
    }
}
```

What is the solution? And why does TypeScript complain?

Comment: Try `if('foo' in arg) { ... } else { ... }`. Typescript won't allow you to access a property that might not exist, but if you check it exists first then there is no problem.

Comment: @kaya3 Perfect! If you write it as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Side-note, beware of unions like yours, where `{foo: 5, bar: 'baz'}` is a possible value because it's assignable to `{bar: string}`, but `'foo' in arg` will be true. It's better if you have a discriminant, like `type FooOrBar = {kind: 'foo', foo: string} | {kind: 'bar', bar: string}` so the union branches are mutually exclusive; then when you test the discriminant, there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I believe this answer will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties

Answer (score 1):

On this line

```
if (arg.foo !== undefined) {
```

it complains, because only `Foo` has the `foo` property, `Bar` doesn't have it.

So, at this point, we can't access `arg.foo` because we don't yet know if `arg` is `Bar` or `Foo`.

#### Solution

I think you could use [User-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```
const isFoo = (maybeFoo: FooOrBar): maybeFoo is Foo => 
  (maybeFoo as Foo).foo !== undefined;
```

Then you can use this to assert the type:

```
function useFooOrBar(arg: FooOrBar) {
  if (isFoo(arg)) {
    console.log(arg.foo);
  } else {
    console.log(arg.bar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is to explicitly include the other properties into both types, but set them as optional and undefined.

```
type Foo = {
    foo: string;
    bar?: undefined;
};

type Bar = {
    foo?: undefined;
    bar: string;
};

type FooOrBar = Foo | Bar;

function useFooOrBar(arg: FooOrBar) {
    if (arg.foo !== undefined) {
        console.log(arg.foo);
    } else {
        console.log(arg.bar);
    }
}
```

[Demo in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKAJADMEBcUAzsAE4CWAdgOYDcW2ARgIZkD8RArlQCYS5qEXg0wBfUVlCQoAITbI0jfHE5Qe-QVWGjmbIqUq1RErFPDR4cAPJl5ZRVagAfOW0mZcPAMbAKcKnViCCtbewAKNhoiULs2AEolTCgUqApcKEiyGgA6FSgAQiQUDQEhXkSMZNSa7wDiOAAbCBzGuBos3JV40RqxKAhG4KSa2vqmlraOqJzWMh6sPqwxIA).

You can also just tell the compiler that the property is there by using [Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). However, you will need to check it for every condition, which can be quite cumbersome:

```
type Foo = {foo: string};
type Bar = {bar: string};

type FooOrBar = Foo | Bar;

function useFooOrBar(arg: FooOrBar) {
    if ('foo' in arg && arg.foo !== undefined) {
        console.log(arg.foo);
    } else if ('bar' in arg && arg.bar !== undefined) {
        console.log(arg.bar);
    }
}
```

[Demo in TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=30&pln=9&pc=56#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAZggXFAzsAJwEsA7AcwF8BuAWAChRIoAhAQwOTQCN2d9jy1evUbR4cAPIE2HFOKgAfFu1p166AK4kAxsCJwSUDbgjipMgBTsyOM9PYBKNPSiuoRdFAsByTHG-uhtZQAGQhUNYAdH5QAIRIKFoAJhDopBBJTqgubrnaBrhwADYQkUVwZFYEZNEIDqq5FFAQRSbunj48BAGkEdWh4VFdcQlGJClpJBlZObmu+SSFJWUVVTVd9bNQFPQUQA).

Comment: After `'foo' in arg` I think there is no need for the undefined check. There is also no need for the `else if` since TypeScript already knows there is only one option remaining.