# How the typescript find a type in a union matched another object literal?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I cannot understand how the typescript infer the type of render in this code.
When I comment the dataIndex, TS cannot infer the type of render.
[see on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBARgXBAUAfCBvAUBTEB2BDAtiHPAG67ACuROF+UIATgJQQC8AfBCQPYCWAJgG4MWXAHNq2WvQbCsEAO4heYgBZg4AZzANe2McIC+EZOnl5CxMpWrbd+lhy58hIzEpXq4UuoyOPUNxwCalJyKkdOAAYAGiCPNQ0IAHIAM1x+dOS4+XFqAEYAJgBmNEMgA)

In this code, I think TS will match type `{ name: (value: number) => void; age: number; weight: string;}`, But not, TS did not infer the type of value.

```js
let b: (| {
    name: (value: number) => void;
    age: number;
    weight: string;
} | {
    name: (value: string) => void;
    weight: number;
}) = {
    name: (value) => 0,
    weight: 'fadfa',
    age: 123
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753 may help you

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code forcing typescript to `narrow` the type of `b`. You're manually setting `b`'s type to a much wider set than needed and typescript happily accepting it. Just to boil down your example to the essence. It's absolutely the same as:

```ts
let b: string | number = 3
```

Obviously `3` is a member of `string | number` and typescript can assign it without any hassle. Widening the type this way gaining you some flexibility in the future. Later you may assign it to a string for example:

```ts
let b: string | number = 3
b = 'string'

let c = 3    // c ~ number
c = 'string' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mL9QvW)

And here is an example of actual [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) based on your type:

```ts
type B = {
    name: (value: number) => void;
    age: number;
    weight: string;
} | {
    name: (value: string) => void;
    weight: number;
}


function executeName(b: B): void {
    if ('age' in b) { // type of `b` get narrowed to the first union constituent
        return b.name(b.age) // early return
    }

    // here `b` type can be only the second union constituent
    b.name('default')
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w18lkW)

Comment: how about this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQLYAdkG8BQyRyIcGEAXMgM5hSgDmA3IcXA5SQK4YBG0LAL74RYAJ5YUAYQDMyALx5WRAPQrkAEzhg4ASRAaIADyoguAG3NNky5FAgHoAfioAKBAHtzpi+YA0yMCQGFTo2AGghibcfNAAlAoAfMgAbh7AGkKiEtIATApKxJraeo7RAETsEOV+tvaOUC7I7l4+sVARwaGYWBFlbfxQCfLJaRlZ+OKSyFIAjAUERVo6+lFU5aTkNXUOho1unt40dIydmN3hgf0xg8Oj6Zn4wtnTUlIFAD4z81+yyL-5Fj4TwgWjIBAIKhvBY7BpuAD6AXhiOQyPhd2QAAZaoIgSJ8UA)
the type of render can be concluded while it didn't comment line 8