# Get Type of Typescript Union Field

Tags: typescript

I have a union type that looks like this:

```js
type Option1 = {
    items: string[];
}
type Option2 = {
    delete: true;
}
type Combined = Option1 | Option2;
```

I would like to define a new variable with the type of the `items` field:

```js
const items_variable:Combined["items"] = ["a", "b"];
```

but this gives me the error `error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Combined'`.

If I was working with values rather than types (which all the existing answers I've seen assume), I could use type narrowing here, however I do not understand how I can do that on an existing type.

It also seems that it would work as expected if `Option2` defined `items` but that does not make sense for my use case.

What type should I use for `items_variable`?

Comment: Can't we do this `const items_variable: Option1["items"] = ["a", "b"];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `items` is only a valid property of *one* of your union members. But anything you do with `Combined` must be valid for *all* union members. So `Combined['items']` is not valid.

---

It's hard to advise more from your contrived code, but the simple answer to just not use the union:

```
const items_variable: Option1["items"] = ["a", "b"];
```

---

Or you could define the `items` property on all members of the union. Note that they do not need to have the same type.

```
type Option1 = {
    items: string[];
}
type Option2 = {
    delete: true;
    items: never;
}
type Combined = Option1 | Option2;

const items_variable:Combined["items"] = ["a", "b"]; // works
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=53&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AjFAvFA3gKCkKgWAgFsBnALiguACcEUBzAbQF0BuPAXz1Eix4yFACYsuAkQAmEADYRSNBgFcI3IsVKUaKCADcI9bnwHQAwkjIAjJhGkS4iVBgA+Q52O54Axqjpa5BQA+voAhoxh1gpUljZ20qwARCRBSewSyWFJADRQSdbp3EA)

---

Or you could use an intersection to filter the union to just the type that has the property you want.

```
const items_variable: (Combined & { items: unknown })["items"] = ["a", "b"];
```

Or

```
const items_variable: (Combined & Option1)["items"] = ["a", "b"];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=77#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AjFAvFA3gKCkKgWAgFsBnALiguACcEUBzAbQF0BuPAXz1Eix4yFACYsuAkQAmEADYRSNBgFcI3IsVKUaKCADcI9bnwHQAwkjIAjJhGkS4iVBgA+Q52O54Axqjpa5BQA+voAhoxh1go0ABSWNnYOAGS4gTpQKigA1ihIAO4oUDwAlKwARCRB5ewSFWHlADRQ5dY13EA)

---

In order to access `['items']` on a type, then all members of that type *must* have that as an accessible property. What all these approaches share is that they make sure that all union members have this property.

Comment: I think `items: never;` is a good solution for my case - it allows access to the type while also clearly stating the intent of the code.

Answer (score 3):

This is how TS unions work. It is by design.

```js
type Option1 = {
    items: string[];
}
type Option2 = {
    delete: true;
}
type Combined = Option1 | Option2;

type Keys = keyof Combined; // never
```

As you see `keyof Combined` returns `never` - empty set of keys.

Because `Option1` and `Option2` does not have any props in common, TS is unsure what property is allowed.

Let's say you have a function which expects either `Option1` or `Option2`. In order to use `Combined` in a safe way you should use custom [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates):

```js
type Option1 = {
    items: string[];
}
type Option2 = {
    delete: true;
}
type Combined = Option1 | Option2;

type Keys = keyof Combined; // never

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const handle = (union: Combined) => {
    if (hasProperty(union, 'items')) {
        const option = union; // Option1
    } else {
        const option = union; // Option2
    }

}
```

Or you can add common property:

```js
type Option1 = {
    tag: '1',
    items: string[];
}
type Option2 = {
    tag: '2',
    delete: true;
}
type Combined = Option1 | Option2;

type CommonProperty = Combined['tag'] // "1" | "2"

const handle = (union: Combined) => {
   if(union.tag==='1'){
       const option = union // Option1
   }
}
```

Another, alternative way is to use `StrictUnion`.

```js
type Option1 = {
    items: string[];
}
type Option2 = {
    delete: true;
}
type Combined = Option1 | Option2;

// credits goes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Union = StrictUnion<Combined>

const items_variable: Union['items'] = ["a", "b"]; // string[] | undefined
```

As you might have noticed, there is a small drawback, `items_variable` might be also `undefined`. This is because of union nature. It can be either one value or another.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking for is an `Intersection` field instead of an `Union` field:

```
    type Combined = Option1 & Option2;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AjFAvFA3gKCigWAgFsBnALinOACcEUBzAbQF0BuPAXz1EljxkKAExZcBKABMIAGwglq9AK4QuvftADCSUgCNGEKeLiJUGAD6CzovH3DQAqimEBpCCHIAeACoA+cR8oCAAPEhQpcigggH4oAGsPJAAzaKhqFAgANwg6LnsBAAU6JDBfABooV2CwiAio5zcPb38A7GrQ8MioRtR3T18AuJ8WVzZ0qEycujsAY1RaIhIKAH0sgEMGdb15amLSrx19QylKgHJiMnIztqgWACJ1+8r7vXvOIA)

```js
type Option1 = {
  items: string[];
}
type Option2 = {
  delete: true;
}
type Combined = Option1 | Option2

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

type Prop<T, K extends UnionKeys<T>> = K extends UnionKeys<T> ? T[K] : never

const items_variable: Prop<Combined, 'items'> = ["a", "b"];
```