# TypeScript: Suppress "Property does not exist on type" for union types

Tags: typescript

```
interface AddressBookingStop {
    street: string
    placeName: string
    city: string
    province: string
    postalCode: string
}

interface ShowBookingStop {
    id: number;
    city: string;
    postal_code: string;
    place_name: string;
    province: string;
    street: string;
    segment_id: number;
    order: number;
}

function formatAddress(stop: AddressBookingStop|ShowBookingStop): string {
    let address = [stop.street || stop.placeName || stop.place_name, stop.city, stop.province].filter(s => s).join(', ');
    const postalCode = stop.postalCode || stop.postal_code;
    if (postalCode) {
        address += ` ${postalCode}`;
    }
    return address;
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN1QgZxwIQHtCBrUAcwGUxCAHZAbwChlXkcxsIwAudziiza0ANoggA5OAFsIfDlEFtkCYGACe8gSHJDWtKIQBuoJFsU69yWoQ5wRAYULo5-C7oC+TJqEixxyJQAFoQA7kSkFNR0jFbA6HwgAK7SAEbQANxWqhrmFFnKNnYiAPoIzq4K+Vai4iUgMpXa5AXChiYgZm7VygoQ3Hk6raw4EOSy4CXxiSnpUMPIhFAuUDNpmUxeTDBJnWDAhCDIMEvScGAYWLg4ABQcdHyX2HgRZDrRtAA+wWGvUTS0ACUg3IsWUIm4yDgmGeOGQAF5kABte60AB0fUhn0+-DoaNqSCksmQ2Nx6IJEHqjQANGS0Tl1LTUfj2qYIABdNEwYAiPx3BEAPnYgLRACtCKAbgByWlSwELcogDjWWxgexOFwIulFNWOCoknHMnX2MoVBbAGDIG7GvUuQFg5RsaFXPDIADUiIABsgACQMG0aiAeT0LLzKbBgJJQI7O2FZLxAA)

TypeScript is complaining:

[image]

But I have `stop.placeName || stop.place_name` there, so one of those two properties is guaranteed to exist.

Is there any way to make TS understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not allow you to access properties of a value that aren't 100% there.

If you just want to suppress all warnings on that line, you can use the `// @ts-ignore` comment [introduced in TS 2.6](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments).

If you want a little less bruteforce method of silencing the compiler, you can pretend to have information you don't really have by casting to the respective types:

```
function formatAddress(stop: AddressBookingStop|ShowBookingStop): string {
    let address = [stop.street || (stop as AddressBookingStop).placeName || (stop as ShowBookingStop).place_name, stop.city, stop.province].filter(s => s).join(', ');
    const postalCode = (stop as AddressBookingStop).postalCode || (stop as ShowBookingStop).postal_code;
    if (postalCode) {
        address += ` ${postalCode}`;
    }
    return address;
}
```

If you want to do make the compiler super happy without cheating (but at the cost of some runtime logic, sadly), you can use a manual typeguard like this:

```
function isShowBookingStop(stop: AddressBookingStop|ShowBookingStop): stop is ShowBookingStop {
    return Boolean((stop as ShowBookingStop).id);
}

function formatAddress(stop: AddressBookingStop|ShowBookingStop): string {
    const street = stop.street || (isShowBookingStop(stop) ? stop.place_name : stop.placeName);
    let address = [street, stop.city, stop.province].filter(s => s).join(', ');
    const postalCode = isShowBookingStop(stop) ? stop.postal_code : stop.postalCode;
    if (postalCode) {
        address += ` ${postalCode}`;
    }
    return address;
}
```

The return value of `stop is ShowBookingStop` tells the compiler that if the returned value is true, the input was of type `ShowBookingStop`. You can then use that information in the `formatAddress` function to determine which property to use. Note that you will have auto-completion in the falsy branch of the ternary operator as well because the compiler understands that if the stop is not a `ShowBookingStop`, it has to be an `AddressBookingStop`.

Which of these options you use, is entirely up to you!

Comment: The `as` solution doesn't look too bad. Would be nice if TS had a more strict version of "as" that only let you cast to subtypes so you couldn't accidentally botch it quite as bad. Oh well, that works for me. Thanks!

Comment: The compiler *does* yell at you if you try casting to something that isn't possible ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+XALmQGcwpQBzAbiwF8stRJZEUAhTHPAIyNPJDU6DJtHhJkAYU55kCPmUo16WGAFcQCMMAD2IfIKgBPSXFIAKOAHkobIugA+yNgEoZeBHuI6ANhAB0PjoU5pY2HGZSLv4ILspYQA))! You could still force it to believe you by using `as unknown as C` in that example however but that doesn't apply to your case.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code `AddressBookingStop|ShowBookingStop` means that TS, by the default, will allow you to use only those properties which are common for both interfaces. THis is safe behavior.
[image]

COnsider this example:

```js
type A = {
    tag: string,
    a: 'a'
}

type B = {
    tag: string,
    b: 'b'
}

type C = keyof (A | B) // tag
```

Nevertheless, there is always a workaround in TypeScript type system :D
YOu can add optional property with `never` type:

```js
type A = {
    tag: string,
    a: 'a'
    b?: never
}

type B = {
    tag: string,
    b: 'b',
    a?: never
}


//"tag" | "a" | "b"
type C = keyof (A | B)

declare var b: B
if (b.a) {
    const x = b.a // never
}
```

You might have noticed that in last example all properties are allowed in a type scope. Don't worry, using disallowed prop `b.a` is impossible because it has `never` type.

Let's go back to our example:

```js
interface AddressBookingStop {
    street: string
    placeName: string
    city: string
    province: string
    postalCode: string
}

interface ShowBookingStop {
    id: number;
    city: string;
    postal_code: string;
    place_name: string;
    province: string;
    street: string;
    segment_id: number;
    order: number;
}

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>



function formatAddress(stop: StrictUnion<AddressBookingStop | ShowBookingStop>): string {
    let address = [stop.street || stop.placeName || stop.place_name, stop.city, stop.province].filter(s => s).join(', ');
    const postalCode = stop.postalCode || stop.postal_code;
    if (postalCode) {
        address += ` ${postalCode}`;
    }
    return address;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN1QgZxwIQHtCBrUAcwGUxCAHZAbwChlXkcxsIwAudziiza0ANoggA5OAFsIfDlEFtkCYGACe8gSHJDWtKIQBuoJFsU69yWoQ5wRAYULo5-C7oC%20TJqEixxyJQAFoQA7kSkFNR0jFbA6HwgAK7SAEbQANxWqhrmFFnKNnYiAPoIzq4K%20Vai4iUgMpXa5AXChiYgZm7VygoQ3Hk6raw4EOSy4CXxiSnpUMPIhFAuUDNpmUxeTBq0KACqIMCEIADSEOo4ADwAKgB8yAC8yNfIEAAekCDoOM-IAPzIEjnQgwX6JCBGDbbdS7QICBBgA5HEAACQgIl2UBuABpnqgRCJ7g8rC93p9vsg4CB1FYAS8AGTIAAKcCgYGA9kuACUIOVlpcAKJvBAiJIuS5I45nC43fGE3FA9Qg563XEgCHQW73cGQ%20beHYoaiKBGSkA3Ilw42Iw7HNEY6A4lXebwwJKddnHZAwJbSOBgDBYXA4AAUHDofCNwBNNrNAeweAiZB00XoAB9AiFwsQk1QaLRbgBKQbkWLKETcSmYeM-J4AbTDtAAdH0K6n0w3G7UkFJZMg2-w6J2xEh6o1cR2cupx3nO%201TBAALqNmDAER%20UOPe44AuNgBWhFAwYA5LijwWFuUQBxrLYwPYnC5HgOm0U744Kn32zPX-YyhUFsAoLBj%2074uAWpbKGwcBVkGyAANRPAABsgAAkDAgQ%20EAeIhCxeMo2BgEkUAgJWgZ4FkXhAA)

More functional approach:

```js
const PROPS = ['street', 'placeName', 'place_name', 'city', 'province'] as const

const computeAddress = (stop: StrictUnion<AddressBookingStop | ShowBookingStop>) =>
    PROPS.reduce((acc, elem) =>
        stop[elem] ? `${acc}, ${stop[elem]}` : acc, ''
    )

const withPostalCode = (address: string) =>
    (stop: StrictUnion<AddressBookingStop | ShowBookingStop>) => {
        const postalCode = stop.postalCode || stop.postal_code;

        return postalCode ? `${address} ${postalCode}` : address
    }


const formatAddress = (stop: StrictUnion<AddressBookingStop | ShowBookingStop>) =>
    withPostalCode(computeAddress(stop))(stop)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIBN1QgZxwIQHtCBrUAcwGUxCAHZAbwChlXkcxsIwAudziiza0ANoggA5OAFsIfDlEFtkCYGACe8gSHJDWtKIQBuoJFsU69yWoQ5wRAYULo5-C7oC%20TJqEixxyJQAFoQA7kSkFNR0jFbA6HwgAK7SAEbQANxWqhrmFFnKNnYiAPoIzq4K%20Vai4iUgMpXa5AXChiYgZm7VygoQ3Hk6raw4EOSy4CXxiSnpUMPIhFAuUDNpmUxeTBq0KACqIMCEIADSEOo4ADwAKgB8yAC8yNfIEAAekCDoOM-IAPzIEjnQgwX6JCBGDbbdS7QICBBgA5HEAACQgIl2UBuABpnqgRCJ7g8rC93p9vsg4CB1FYAS8AGTIAAKcCgYGA9kuACUIOVlpcAKJvBAiJIuS5I45nC43fGE3FA9Qg563XEgCHQW73cGQ%20beHYoaiKBGSkA3Ilw42Iw7HNEY6A4lXeJjlEAcZlcgDyTMoj2QAG0AOR9biB3GB2pIKSyMPICNiJD1RqxwM5dQpgzGUwQQMAXUpP1dHG8RbAKkI0loSUgGCwuB%20TwAFBw6HwjcATTazbXsHgImQdNF6AAfQIhcLEAdUGi0W4ASketysTK9PoAdNh0EkkI3G4gELj0RBpAuHkvlL0Z-6j9J8wCAAYAEgY%2048uOfLdo15Ex9zHnvyB8Pu4aBlYc4lsc7qhGoQRMrYYD2E4Lh%20numC9jggzkKe55sM2M5tvC1rIpcPb1v2UQzsgo7BGE5GDjO86LrEF5sKW1jwYhFR%20p%20a5FAhjhccOo48Xx9hlBUWRWMo2BgEkUAgOxxRISgD7PnAaH1h4yDPqJAkuP%20gGUhpeBWFsLqQWWMBLNIcBgKReAoZ%20BFWqaJHGQQk4UTE1HjnR050IxZ5WNBYCwRxekQI25SVtWED2TgeF0HOc6JbQ4FAA)

Comment: That `StrictUnion` helper is really cool! I've wanted something like that several times now. I almost wonder if they should make it a compiler flag to make `|` behave that way.

Comment: Yest it is cool. But some times it is not enough. See this : find Second part ,https://dev.to/captainyossarian/how-to-type-react-props-as-a-pro-2df2