# Inferred type from arrays of narrow and wide types

Tags: typescript

```
type ItemNew = { text: string };
type ItemExist = { text: string, id: number };
 
function fn(
  itemsNew: Array<ItemNew>,
  itemsExist: Array<ItemExist>
) {
  const items = [...itemsNew, ...itemsExist];
  // const items: ItemNew[]
}
```

Why `items` is `ItemNew[]` and not `Array<ItemNew | ItemExist>`? It seems that information about the wide type (`ItemExist`) is simply lost.

Comment: Because of [Best common type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#best-common-type) inference

Comment: @RickyMo I did not know that this behavior is explicitly documented. Thanks for the link!

Comment: `ItemNew | ItemExist` is logically the same as `ItemNew`. If something is either a fruit or an apple, then you might as well just say it is a fruit.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```js
type ItemNew = { text: string };
type ItemExist = { text: string, id: number };

type Union = ItemNew | ItemExist
declare var union: Union

const elem = union.text // only text property is allowed
```

Because `text` is common for both items you are allowed to get `text` property.

Because nobody knows whether `var union` contains `id` or not. Allowing `id` prop in this case will be unsound (might cause runtime error).

Let's go back to your example:

```js
type ItemNew = { text: string };
type ItemExist = { text: string, id: number };

function fn(
    itemsNew: Array<ItemNew>,
    itemsExist: Array<ItemExist>
) {
    const items =  [...itemsNew, ...itemsExist];
}
```

In fact `items` is a union of `Array<ItemNew> | Array<ItemExist>`. Same rule is applied. Property `text` is the only one safe property.

If you want to be able to get `id` proeprty you might wonna use this helper:

```js
type ItemNew = { text: string };
type ItemExist = { text: string, id: number };

// credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>


function fn(
    itemsNew: Array<ItemNew>,
    itemsExist: Array<ItemExist>
) {
    const items: Array<StrictUnion<ItemNew | ItemExist>> = [...itemsNew, ...itemsExist];
    items[0].text // ok
    items[0].id // number | undefined
}
```

Comment: Your example and mine are different. In your case, it remains possible to refer to the id with the help of a typeguard, for example: `if ('id' in union) { const elem = union.id }`. In my case, the information about the id is completely lost.

Comment: It seems like my problem is easier to solve like this: `const items: Array<ItemNew | ItemExist> = [...itemsNew, ...itemsExist]`, because I don't need to mix types in the end. But thanks for the solution with StrictUnion!

Comment: @Dartess yes, seems like an overengineering from my side :D