# Expecting an error but code compiles fine

Tags: typescript

Given this code,

```js
interface TaskStartedEvent {
    type: "started",
    task: string
}

interface TaskLogEvent {
    type: "log",
    task: string,
    message: string
}

interface TaskFailedEvent {
    type: "failed",
    task: string,
    error?: string
}

interface FreeLog {
    message: string | Error,
    meta?: unknown
}

interface UndefinedTask {
    task?: undefined
}

type TaskEvent = TaskStartedEvent | TaskLogEvent | TaskFailedEvent;
type RuntimeEvent = (FreeLog & UndefinedTask) | TaskEvent;

function foo(ev: RuntimeEvent) {
    console.log(ev);    
}
foo({ message: "bar", type: "log" });
```

Why isn't the Typescript compiler failing here?

I pass a `type` field so it cannot be a `(FreeLog & UndefinedTask)` type, but I don't pass a `task` field so it cannot be a `TaskEvent` as well.

This code compiles with no errors ([typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwM4GsDKY5SQAmAogG4TjIDeAUMg8mAJ4AOEAXMgEQb6EQi3ADT1G%20bFz5RQAc1oBfWrVCRYiFOmwAZAPazylMDTEMW7LtwA2%20kaaaYsUsDJCzRjZAFsIGDHFlOZGk5RWVVaHgkNEcAMThgK0FDKjpPcyDueETBO3THZ1d3e2goXSgAfkLQpRVwSI1kWKgICD1ZE08fPwCgkLdkAB9kEigyqA9GH3wq5ABXECwQXQB3EDC6tSiUAFUQIggYUEEtLE7xR1mFg6OQQQ2MmOwU4wBeJ9x%20Yhehj-af4aneI5UgUcAAblojwASgswMAfD93gAKZqtdrIABkyD2N2ORFOAEpfqcXpDaDAFgh4boQMgYLpdMiIGQuLDwAiIC9iWlGAhaRhdEkAHQ2WTMsiE8GeMIMpnUby%20fyBSwAIwIIiYbEyYu4yAUUqAA) link).

Comment: Here's a [minimal example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwM4GsAyB7AcwFEA3CcZAbwChk7kwBPABwgC5kAiAG0M4G5a9MJiwcMYKKAKD6yALYQMGOAXbIJUkDOoBfatVCRYiFADEoECPgJUhdRctXrN05AB9kRKFDxRB+tRMrMgASgCu4MCKpORgyAC8yBZWNh5oojax4ILUMJEIYMB4IMgweHgAFBAkHBFRMWTgAJR2cgglGHjcEAB0vATVJM38cnoG5VWUCkoqahycAEZwUJwANAws6jx8yLojQA). It appears that the `Object literal may only specify known properties` error will only be raised when specifying a field that isn't present on _any_ of the types in the union. Not sure if this is intended behaviour or not.

Comment: It's also worth noting that while this _looks_ like a discriminated union, it's not since `FreeLog` doesn't specify a constant string type.

Comment: @superhawk610 yeah, I know it's not a proper discriminated union. I still expect it to behave correctly. It looks like a bug to me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What error do you expect and where?

Comment: @captain-yossarian expecting either something like `unexpected field type` or `expected field task`, when I pass the `{ message: "bar", type: "log" }` to `foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in this line: `(FreeLog & UndefinedTask)`.
Above intersection produces this type:

```js
type Debug<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop]
}

// type Result = {
//     message: string | Error;
//     meta?: unknown;
//     task?: undefined;
// }
type Result = Debug<FreeLog & UndefinedTask>
```

We ended up with one required property: `message`. Let's test it:

```js
function foo(ev: RuntimeEvent) {
    console.log(ev);
}

foo({ message: '2' });
```

But why it also allows `type`?  `{ message: string, type: 'log' }` is not a type of any union.

```js
type Check<T> = T extends RuntimeEvent ? true : false

// true
type Result = Check<{ message: 'string', type: 'log' }>
```

`{ message: 'string', type: 'log' }` extends `RuntimeEvent` because `FreeLog & UndefinedTask` is a part of it and it expects minimum one property `message` to meet the minimum requirements.

We know why it is allowed, but what about `type`? Why it is allowed to use only `log` value? Because when you started typing `type` property, TS started to check your arguments. It appears that only union with `log` has both `message` and `type` properties.

You may or may not provide `task` property. It is up to you. TS does not complain because technically, your argument meet requirements.

To make it work in a way you expect, you can use `StrictUnion` helper:

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = 
    T extends any 
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>
```

Full example:

```js
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

interface TaskStartedEvent {
    type: "started",
    task: string
}

interface TaskLogEvent {
    type: "log",
    task: string,
    message: string
}

interface TaskFailedEvent {
    type: "failed",
    task: string,
    error?: string
}

interface FreeLog {
    message: string | Error,
    meta?: unknown
}

interface UndefinedTask {
    task?: undefined
}

type TaskEvent = TaskStartedEvent | TaskLogEvent | TaskFailedEvent;


type RuntimeEvent = StrictUnion<(FreeLog & UndefinedTask) | TaskEvent>;

function foo(ev: RuntimeEvent) {
    console.log(ev);
}

foo({ message: 'string', type: 'log' }); // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwNIRAZwDwBUB8UAvFLlBAB7ARwAmmpUA-FANYZIBmjAXFHBABuEAE4BuAFChIUAMrARCAMbB4yOAAkIAG0gi8AGlIBBbdsJEJUa40rU6DAIZwQVmyzIAyKAAVHI4ARHbWwAJQglJBFabABRCiVtAFdaCGw1FHQsPFNzI3YQLlJ8IwFhEXxCPjLRSSlwaHlFFQy4PAs5BWVVRBQtXVFDYokJBDhqEU5HJWhcR0xWeX9qWljhcagAbzdraQg%20ACJMYGWIWgODHagThb5jxTgAcwkAXxGxiamZ0nnWABkkI81jRgFsrntDtpARdwb87l0npcbFAALYQTCYRyPfZQe5jZ5vUbjURfWa-ABijgQ2jOwI222REKgBym1LOMMZcNxCMeSJsohEUSY8IeBPexMm02g5JEEAgAMeYORaIxWJxeKeUAAPlBYiJBSI%20dY0SdhVAknBWHAkAB3OCvcWfKWwOgQThjM5zBZKmw3Vhmi2pd0CWgO%20oyL2sOmgkiRpYBWnrUE6yMK6Pan4LSls1ZJurh6ChC2BNHpkhNbqtbAAChlcoVUG88CDHtokYAlBnI9H8HVOBaVOooJwkEhq0I%20EXxghS0nOwybJE4JgkDSAHRQx7jwTtySEkdjzao9GY7F8ADkGse56MTPPm-PUBeu6gAHpX%20QKJAVGdyPqohIQA)

You can find more interesting examples in my [blog](https://catchts.com/)

**Summary**

`FreeLog & UndefinedTask` does not expect you to provide the `task` property. At least `task` is not required whereas `TaskEvent` requires `task`. SO, you ended up in a situation with two element in a union. One element requires `task` and another one not.

> .. inconsistent with how a discriminated union would behave ...

Please keep in mind, your union is not discriminated. Make `task` required prop in `UndefinedTask`. It will help.

**Discriminated union**
If you wan to use [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions), also [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), you should create a `type` for each element of a union. The `type` property should be different for each element in the union.
See example:

```js
interface TaskStartedEvent {
    type: "started",
    task: string
}

interface TaskLogEvent {
    type: "log",
    task: string,
    message: string
}

interface TaskFailedEvent {
    type: "failed",
    task: string,
    error?: string
}

interface FreeLog {
    message: string | Error,
    meta?: unknown
}

interface UndefinedTask {
    task: undefined
}

type UndefinedEvent = (FreeLog & UndefinedTask) & {
    type: 'undefined'
}

type TaskEvent = TaskStartedEvent | TaskLogEvent | TaskFailedEvent;
type RuntimeEvent = UndefinedEvent | TaskEvent;

function foo(ev: RuntimeEvent) {
    console.log(ev);
}
foo({ message: "bar", type: "log" }); // error
```

Also, please take a look on example from the docs:

```js
type Shape =
  | { kind: "circle"; radius: number }
  | { kind: "square"; x: number }
  | { kind: "triangle"; x: number; y: number };
```

Property `kind` serves as a tag for each element in the union.
For instance, F# also uses [discriminated unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/discriminated-unions):

```ml
type Shape =
    | Rectangle of width : float * length : float
    | Circle of radius : float
    | Prism of width : float * float * height : float
```

As you might have noticed, `Rectangle`, `Circle` and `Prism` are just tags.

Comment: That strict union trick works, but I guess I still wonder about `You may or may not provide task property. It is up to you. TS does not complain because technically, your argument meet requirements.`. Why is it the case with regular union? After all, if I provide `type: "log"`, the compiler should expect that I provide all of the fields in `TaskLogEvent`, no?

Comment: It looks like, because both `FreeLog & UndefinedTask` and `TaskLogEvent` expect me to provide a `task`, it's enough to only satisfy one of those (e.g. only satisfy the `task` requirement set by `FreeLog & UndefinedTask`), but that's still a bit unintuitive for me because it seems inconsistent with how a discriminated union would behave (if I make the `task` inside `UndefinedTask` an actual string, it will work as expected)

Comment: So the only way to do a strict union (without using that helper) is to have a fully discriminated union (unlike what I did).
It still looks like something I'd expect the TS compiler to handle, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: It is better to stick with discriminated unions.