# Issue with REACT component discriminated props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to develop a REACT component using TypeScript, and to be more precise, using discrimination union types.
What I want to achieve is that the `props` of my component can have the `context` prop, and, if it does, then the `name` props is of type `keyof T`. Otherwise, `name` is a simple `string`.

Here's the first example:

```
interface IBaseProps {
    label: string;
}

interface IWithContext<T> extends IBaseProps {
    context: T;
    name: keyof T;
}

interface IWithoutContext extends IBaseProps {
    name: string;
}

type IProps<T> = IWithContext<T> | IWithoutContext;

const TestComp = <T extends {}>(props: IProps<T>) => {
    const testMethod = () => {
        if (props.context) { // Property 'context' does not exist on type 'IProps<T>'. Property 'context' does not exist on type 'IWithoutContext'.
            console.log('Test_1');
        }
    }
    
    return <p>Hello World</p>
}
```

In this case, the issue is that the property `context` is not in `IWithoutContext`. Easy fix: add the `context` in that interface as well with `null` type.

```
interface IBaseProps {
    label: string;
}

interface IWithContext<T> extends IBaseProps {
    context: T;
    name: keyof T;
}

interface IWithoutContext extends IBaseProps {
    context: never;
    name: string;
}

type IProps<T> = IWithContext<T> | IWithoutContext;

const TestComp = <T extends {}>(props: IProps<T>) => {
    const testMethod = () => {
        if (props.context !== null) { // OK
            if (props.context[props.name]) { // Type 'string | keyof T' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
                console.log('Test_1');
            }
        }
    }
    
    return <p>Hello World</p>
}
```

But now, I've a different error: apparently, typescript is not able to understand that `props.name` is of type `keyof T`, based on the fact that `props.context` is different from `null`.

Though, I think that, due to the interfaces, it should be inferred that `props.name` is of type `keyof T`.

What am I missing here?

---

EDIT: here's a more comprehensive example.

```
interface IValidationRule {
    id: string;
}

interface IValidation {
    [key: string]: IValidationRule[];
}

class MyCustomClass {
    validation: IValidation;
}

interface IBaseProps {
    label: string;
}

interface IWithContext<T> extends IBaseProps {
    context: T;
    name: keyof T;
}

interface IWithoutContext extends IBaseProps {
    context: never;
    name: string;
    validation: IValidation;
}

type IProps<T> = IWithContext<T> | IWithoutContext;

const TestComp = <T extends MyCustomClass>(props: IProps<T>) => {
    const testMethod = () => {
        let validation : IValidation[] = null;

        /* In case context is defined, I can use 'name' to retrieve the validation. */
        if (props.context !== null) {
            validation = props.context.validation[props.name];
        }
        /* Otherwise, if context is null, validation shuold be provided in the props. */
        else {
            validation = props.validation;
        }
    }

    return <p>Hello World</p>
}
```

Apparently, the problem is that type discrimination does get along with generic type T or `null` value.

By the way, the real example is really like this.. Just, the class has more properties.

Also, I've tried the `hasProperty` approach, and it works great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options to handle it.

**First one**, make [user defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IBaseProps {
    label: string;
}

interface IWithContext<T> extends IBaseProps {
    context: T;
    name: keyof T;
}

interface IWithoutContext extends IBaseProps {
    name: string;
}

type IProps<T> = IWithContext<T> | IWithoutContext;

const hasProperty = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: Obj, prop: Prop)
    : obj is Obj & Record<Prop, unknown> =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop);

const TestComp = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(props: IProps<T>) => {
    const testMethod = () => {
        if (hasProperty(props, 'context')) {
            console.log('Test_1');
            props.context // Record<string, unknown>
        }
    }

    return <p>Hello World</p>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgEkAhFAZyQAUcxOcAN7k4YuABsUAIyQSAXHE4woNAOYUAvpRp0GTVgHVgMABYBhCLSQAPGAB4AKgD44tutQAmg9l179BEXE4NCs6O0VHCmDqFBAkRQBrJABPCEw4KPJtKmt9NGYWYzMIAFcYS2s7NzskLx8Obj4IAWFRcVj4xWVVag1syhgUsELmgSdXAF4jEwsw9wm4AB8ZkvLK8JgKclDqZThTLjH6Ibhp%20wB5aQArABo4MZqPbyUVdWcACggbxSu7uDA-EUYwAlO0xIpvtc4MBBH84AAyRBIUJQTz2Mb3UrURLUCAAd2oU2c4LgfxRMAAdICIDBacMkJTDpwLoTjrAUpS0CgJBIvjd7jSwCDtrt9o4kMpLOAznAnE86i9kKj0T11FicXjCc5PkLOIoWGNOBMQWdXEFxGL4HRlABZJAlTyyj6mybm0nBYAZD7M9lDD56%2074XabfAg00W4JRkJWTgQCSMiQQNQffAS5QAfQAjGHotGo3qufNqgB6EvIlX2NV9DW4glEj3ibTBHLBIgwUpQahysDOAASciTcEM0Ak6JLveyQA)

**`hasProperty`** - is a custom type guard.

**Second one**, you can relax your union:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IBaseProps {
    label: string;
}

interface IWithContext<T> extends IBaseProps {
    context: T;
    name: keyof T;
}

interface IWithoutContext extends IBaseProps {
    name: string;
}

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;
// credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type IProps<T> = StrictUnion<IWithContext<T> | IWithoutContext>;

const TestComp = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(props: IProps<T>) => {
    const testMethod = () => {
        if (props.context) {
            props.context // Record<string, unknown>
        }
    }

    return <p>Hello World</p>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgEkAhFAZyQAUcxOcAN7k4YuABsUAIyQSAXHE4woNAOYUAvpRp0GTVgHVgMABYBhCLSQAPGAB4AKgD44tutQAmg9l179BEXE4NCs6O0VHCmDqFBAkRQBrJABPCEw4KPJtKmt9NGYWYzMIAFcYS2s7NzskLx8Obj4IAWFRcVj4xWVVag1syhgUsGYAVWpgKwBpVM4nVwBeTJqPb2WAfjhktIzHOEVqJAA3egpyIZG4AGUVYAxxyeoACTkRqCcAGkyAQQkJRfaYj27jqaxQ1BSgLgmz2ADI4DwULBgCgJPZkKEoJ57ABRGxoCSlTxIewPaazJy-f5fbbpTLOL6HE5QZyuA7HU6DYbMG6qe4TKzzOBLXl3GBk56veifelcy4sZoCIUi278x72IomCxhdxCgA%20Ri1ZQqOrszjOoWoykySGUlnAwrgThWoMEGOg2J66i%20pWoiWoEAA7tRWQAKMABRQKgLzACUwtcQXElutdGUAFkkCVPI7Q-GFomocFgBlwwEAHSW8IweNJ4L1uARlqcSum%20AAenbiCQmM9tz6Pr9AeDziL4m0wRywSIMFKUGoTrAzhefwgcEM0Ak2PbS%20yQA)

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) answer for more explanation of `StrictUnion`

More information about using discriminated union with react components you can find in my blog [here](https://catchts.com/unions) and [here](https://catchts.com/react-props)

**SUMMARY**

Using `T extends {}` is considered a bad practice. Type of `{}` is tooo wide. Consider using `Record<string, unknown>` instead.

`IProps` is not a discriminated union.

```js
interface IWithContext<T> extends IBaseProps {
    context: T;
    name: keyof T;
}

interface IWithoutContext extends IBaseProps {
    name: string;
}

type IProps<T> = IWithContext<T> | IWithoutContext;
```

To make it a discriminated union, you should provide a special property witch will be required in each union and will be different. For example:

```js
import React from 'react';

interface IBaseProps {
    label: string;
}

interface IWithContext<T> extends IBaseProps {
    tag: 'with'
    context: T;
    name: keyof T;
}

interface IWithoutContext extends IBaseProps {
    tag: 'without'
    name: string;
}


type IProps<T> = IWithContext<T> | IWithoutContext;

const TestComp = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(props: IProps<T>) => {
    const testMethod = () => {
        if (props.tag === 'with') {
            props.context // Record<string, unknown>
        }
    }

    return <p>Hello World</p>
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgEkAhFAZyQAUcxOcAN7k4YuABsUAIyQSAXHE4woNAOYUAvpRp0GTVgHVgMABYBhCLSQAPGAB4AKgD44tutQAmg9l179BEXE4GBQ1RXwAdxNTfFFxNCs6O0VHCmDqFBAkRQBrJABPCEw4NPJtKmt9NGYWYzMIAFcYS2s7NzskLx8Obj4IAWF4sVDwgmiG5riMrJylFXUtSnIYArBa-oEnVwBeIxjW5IcXOAAffcmWpPcKckTqZVKkZUtwOD2nDo9vRCREqE89mUqmoagANHBGtRctQIJFqM5nAAKMABRQsTacbYASneriCCSsjzoygAskgGp53nAkbidvjhsE4MASiiAgA6UbvHZ7KIxfC4glMpmogacdn3I5wAD00t%20-0BwPUEKhMLhCMZwW0WsowSIMEaUGocHsYGcAAk5BIIHBDNAJIDpWbykA)

Please see example of discriminated union from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

Comment: I'm gonna try the first proposal. Though, two things: (1) in the real example, I'm using `T extends MyCustomClass`. Still, even if not using `{}`, the error persists. Moreover, I DO need the `exnteds MyCustomClass` because inside `testMethod` I'm going to access properties that are defined in `MyCustomClass`. (2) I thought that the the `context` property in the second example is the discriminator property.. But, in one case is a value different from `null`, and in the other is `null`

Comment: @Jolly please provide an example from your real code, I mean with error

Comment: i really like the last option using a `tag`.

Comment: @captain, the error is `a.context[a.name]` can't be figured out by the compiler what it is.

Comment: The problem with the `tag` is that i'm adding another discriminator property, when instead `context` should have that role. BTW, I've edited the first message. Also, `hasProperty` approac works

Comment: @Jolly as far as I understood `validation` variable should be an array, but you are trying to assign an object to it. `validation = props.context.validation[props.name]`. Is this correct?

Comment: @windmaomao this is because `context` is expected to be `Record<string, unknown>`. Please share reproducable example of the error you are getting