# Typescript intersection of union and intersection not erroring

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

I would like to have a type that ensures an object has a type of `A` or `B` or `A and B`.  However one of the cases that I think should fail is not.  I'm sure it's something stupid I just can't see it yet.

```js
interface ValueSelector
{
    type: "id" | "value_string"
    value: string
}

interface TemporalSelector
{
    id: number
}

type Selector = (ValueSelector & TemporalSelector) | ValueSelector | TemporalSelector

// Should error
const e0: Selector = {}
const e1: Selector = { id: 0, value: "" }  // <-- does not error
const e2: Selector = { type: "id" }
const e3: Selector = { type: "value_string" }
const e4: Selector = { value: "" }
const e5: Selector = { value: "" }

// Should pass
const a1: Selector = { id: 0 }
const a2: Selector = { type: "id", value: "" }
const a3: Selector = { type: "value_string", value: "" }
const a4: Selector = { id: 0, type: "id", value: "" }
const a5: Selector = { id: 0, type: "value_string", value: "" }
```

Answer (score 2):

`e1` does not trigger an error because `{ id: 0, value: "" }` is already assignable to `TemporalSelector` since it expects only `id` property.

In order to make it work you can use the [`StrictUnion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) helper:

```js
interface ValueSelector {
    type: "id" | "value_string"
    value: string
}

interface TemporalSelector {
    id: number
}

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = 
    T extends any 
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>


type Selector = (ValueSelector & TemporalSelector) | StrictUnion<ValueSelector | TemporalSelector>

// Should error
const e0: Selector = {}
const e1: Selector = { id: 0, value: "" }  // error
const e2: Selector = { type: "id" }
const e3: Selector = { type: "value_string" }
const e4: Selector = { value: "" }
const e5: Selector = { value: "" }

// Should pass
const a1: Selector = { id: 0 }
const a2: Selector = { type: "id", value: "" }
const a3: Selector = { type: "value_string", value: "" }
const a4: Selector = { id: 0, type: "id", value: "" }
const a5: Selector = { id: 0, type: "value_string", value: "" }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGpwDYFcIGUIYQJgD2UyA3gFDK3JgCeADhAFzIBEwAJh8gD6cAbphwB9AM5gooAOYcadEdjbIpMkLKoBfKlVCRYiFABUIAWyZlM%20QsTKVFtHuxBZzAI2g69jFsgBVEGASEABpCAYJAB4TAD5kAF5kE2QIAA9IEG4JFOQAfmQAa0iSGDzXCCFoAG4qPxRcaWBiIJCQAAkCFihYgBoUgEEMDATkpzyMrJzkOBAGZAnC1IAyZAAFOCgwYExogCUiMm5ogFF0hGxuCGi20Iio2OHRgZKGMpS4gZAq6DiEyrVKB1erMRrNVrBUKxMbIJoySHtLoYHr9T56UH%20WxEUjkZIACnQKmx9nIazMlmsGBJuIAlAI4RCwHcQNEiTgaQ5BBSrFAbAQcWQ4noAPQiuEACxIWAw3DSUCgZCoCFCUjSAAZ2Jy8ZRdCqQGqIABGLUC0lJSjIFzIdUDZQ4dgcPjaWhi%20WKqDK1VgNIAJlNdlxFoo9DBjp4zq9Bp9EAAzAHBTqQw1HfaIJJmppI-rDQAWBPm5IhtOO7PetIAVgLQaLyBLnEjVDduClMrlTDgEgkUbVcBNcLNNct1vVyD15bg-oHgYctZTnAjdtEqidY57Prg8enieDoZYqeXGY08iXKlLa5zG-z28Lw%2047Fte5Xi7ry-P4%20jsyrN6HIZHA3nDg0yPOQOFPB0GzHIA)

Comment: This is great.  Thank you.  I usually forget this Liskov Substitution Principle/rule.  The `StrictUnion` is exactly what I need.  The `tag` property will not work however as they allow `A` or `B` but not `A` or `B` or `A and B`.

Comment: Thank you. Also I did not think about Liskov SP in this context. Nice