# Trying to implement a function that takes two out of three possible types of arguments

Tags: typescript

I have three different types

```
type A = 'a'
type B = 'b'
type C = 'c'
```

I want to type a function either accepts `A`, `C` or `B`, `C` but not `A`, `B`, and `C`.

Here is my attempt

```
type A = 'a'
type B = 'b'
type C = 'c'
type BaseArgs = {
    c: C
}
type VariantA = {
    a: A
} & BaseArgs

type VariantB = {
    b: B,
} & BaseArgs

function fn(arg: VariantA | VariantB) {
}
```

But turns out it doesn't work as expected, as

```
const b: B = 'b'
const a: A = 'a'
const c: C = 'c'

fn({b,a,c})  // this would not error out
```

`fn({b,a,c})`  should be giving an error but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve desired behavior, you should wrap your union type in `StrictUnion` helper:

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>


type A = 'a'
type B = 'b'
type C = 'c'

type BaseArgs = {
    c: C
}

type VariantA = {
    a: A
} & BaseArgs

type VariantB = {
    b: B,
} & BaseArgs

function fn(arg: StrictUnion<VariantA | VariantB>) {}


const b: B = 'b'
const a: A = 'a'
const c: C = 'c'

fn({ a, c }) // ok
fn({ b, c }) // ok

fn({ b, a, c })  // this would not error out
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAVQHYEsD2SDSMIGcA8AKgHxwC8chcMAHmDEgCa6VwD8cA1jmgGasAuOEhgA3GACcA3KEiw4AZTASUAYzDJ0SABIwANrAlEANJQCCevaTKg4d1rXpMWAQyQRb9jlQBkcAAouEmAoLnr4AEowqmgSjPgAojSqegCujDD4mhjYeEQWVqbcEHyUxKYi4hLEpEKVkjIgstDwSirq2UhE1orKahqoGLoGkiZloBPgLXBm5HAA5C7zzfIAQnPzAEbLU-IAwhuqOyvwqy64MGYSAOYsFADennaqQnugAL6TcvAAakGhSDAsweTzgLiEZg%20cD8ZwuV1uX2mfxUbjA6xBIHscE2QlWxihMPOlxuuEmvFSSHUWjgvCQAAogtchG1%20p18MiAUC4AAfOAc1GrYgASjg90%20TQlMSQuDA2NxG22oClMrBEI2SyVGBVLzgBwo8yOZPp9zBplUcHeIoA9Fa4GhOKBaXSTZszRbrbb7UbndjTC43Za7Da4GAABYoFgAdzQqT0jGEaFlkgksTtqTAQA)

You did not have an error here `fn({ b, a, c })` because this argument is assignable to both union types.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like TypeScript is being nice here--the object is both a valid `VariantA` or `VariantB` so it allows it, despite having an extra variable if you were to "choose" just one or the other. If you don't want this, you could specify explicitly:

```
type VariantA = {
    a: A;
    b?: never; // This line!
} & BaseArgs
```

(and do the same for `VariantB`)

Answer (score 1):

`{a:A, b:B, c:C}` matches the union of your acceptable types.

use an overload to specify you only want one or the other:

```
function fn(arg: VariantA): void;
function fn(arg: VariantB): void;
function fn(arg: VariantB | VariantA) {
}
```

[typscript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDkBDJAoUkoCEHICMMtoBhfJAY2PGhxQGcIYAnAcwfwG90o%20pKALiil0AX0y0oANRQsAligB2wOIh78oKYTAA04qADJcjZuwbpJ2WQuXA863vwLCc%20sUZNNWHS%20gBmAK5KlMDyAPZKUP5KABRybMI2iiowAJTCAG7h8gAmANwBwaERUTHx7ElyKfYZUNl5hUEhYZHRcQlVtip4AD4y1XbpUDwS6JSRDMBQLrgUROOT09qwFGiLSlMCwuSIVBgBcVwEuii6lGJpfAD011DAABbynM9aURAsLOEsh7HH55cbndHq9Xkpwst3p9vr8uGcLlcoLd7k8XpxwZCoB8vj90EA)