# How can I enforce different typescript interface classes based on a type condition in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

I am trying to enforce certain properties of a component depending on the type of the component... Basically I have a main interface with heroStyling types:

```
export type HeroStyling = 'SimpleForm' | 'WithTickerHeader' | 'WithTagLineHeader' | 'WithRating'

export interface AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: HeroStyling
  cta: string
  ctaUrl: string
  image: FluidObject
  imageAlt: string
}
```

and I am extending this to four other classes depending on the type of the heroStyling key:

```
export interface AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: HeroStyling
  cta: string
  ctaUrl: string
  image: FluidObject
  imageAlt: string
}

export interface WithTagLineHeader extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  headingTagLine: string
  heading: string
  leadParagraph: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}
export interface WithTickerHeader extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  textCenter: boolean
  leadParagraph?: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}

export interface SimpleForm extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  textCenter: boolean
  heading: string
  leadParagraph?: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}
export interface WithRating extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  textCenter: true
  reviewStars?: boolean
}
```

My question is how can I enforce an extended class properties depending on what the type heroStyling is on my component without TypeScript complaining about one property not existing on a type? I need to deconstruct all props as I render according to their truthy or falsey values.

```
 const CampaignHero = ({ 
    heroStyling, textCenter, reviewStars, headingTagLine, 
    heading, leadParagraph, bulletPoints, cta, ctaUrl, image, imageAlt }
    : WithTagLineHeader | WithTickerHeader | SimpleForm | WithRating ): React.ReactElement => {
return (
    <section>
          {headingTagLine && (
            <div      
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: headingTagLine }}
            />
          )}
          {heading && <h1>{heading}</h1>}
          {leadParagraph && <p>{leadParagraph}</p>}
          {bulletPoints && (
            <div
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: bulletPoints }}
            />
          )}
            <Button href={ctaUrl}>{cta}</Button>
          {reviewStars && (
              <HeroRating />
          )}
        </div>
          <Img alt={imageAlt} fluid={image} loading="eager" />
    </section>
  )
}
```

Question after captain-yossarian great help:
If I render the component as below I get no errors but I should since bulletPoints is not part of the WithRating interface. TS complains only when one of the defined interface properties is missing, not when there is one that shouldn't exist.

```
<AdaptiveHero
        heroStyling={'WithRating'}
        reviewStars={true}
        textCenter={true}
        cta={hero.cta}
        ctaUrl={hero.ctaUrl}
        image={hero.image.fluid}
        imageAlt={hero.image.alt}
        bulletPoints={hero.bulletPoints}
      />
```

Comment: `reviewStars` is not exists in your unions at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a union, you are allowed to use only common properties which are shared across each union type.
You are not allowed to use `headingTagLine` without narrowing.
Please see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types):

> Sometimes you’ll have a union where all the members have something in common. For example, both arrays and strings have a slice method. If every member in a union has a property in common, you can use that property without narrowing:
> This is the only way to preserve type safety.

In order to narrow the union type, you should create [custom typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), which has impact on runtime.

However, it is possible to handle it without affection runtime. COnsider this example:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react'

type FluidObject = {
  tag: 'FluidObject'
}

export type HeroStyling = 'SimpleForm' | 'WithTickerHeader' | 'WithTagLineHeader' | 'WithRating'

export interface AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: HeroStyling
  cta: string
  ctaUrl: string
  image: FluidObject
  imageAlt: string
}

export interface AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: HeroStyling
  cta: string
  ctaUrl: string
  image: FluidObject
  imageAlt: string
}

export interface WithTagLineHeader extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  headingTagLine: string
  heading: string
  leadParagraph: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}
export interface WithTickerHeader extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  textCenter: boolean
  leadParagraph?: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}

export interface SimpleForm extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  textCenter: boolean
  heading: string
  leadParagraph?: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}


type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
  T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

const Button: FC<{ href: string }> = ({ children }) => <span> children</span>

const CampaignHero = ({
  heroStyling, textCenter, reviewStars, headingTagLine,
  heading, leadParagraph, bulletPoints, cta, ctaUrl, image, imageAlt }
  : StrictUnion<WithTagLineHeader | WithTickerHeader | SimpleForm>): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <section>
      {headingTagLine && (
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: headingTagLine }}
        />
      )}
      {heading && <h1>{heading}</h1>}
      {leadParagraph && <p>{leadParagraph}</p>}
      {bulletPoints && (
        <div
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: bulletPoints }}
        />
      )}
      <Button href={ctaUrl}>{cta}</Button>
      {reviewStars && (
        <HeroRating />
      )}
      <Img alt={imageAlt} fluid={image} loading="eager" />
    </section >
  )
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDMwCeYSBANgK7AAJgHkARgCskGOAF5czOHBgoA5gC46%20fkLGSmzEqyQAPSLCWduACSRUAyhx7AAditl07oMDyT5oIWjgAHzoAdWAYAAsAFWA0AGtbGxRBW0CQ2nCo6NUAGRckZNSodLCIyIQUGBcVFmYTM3gXGFtydG4AQUEUMGqAN0LbCABZFBcABSowAGd5RUihh3YnVw0be0cahTgMFA1pmCgtxV2AVSgefcPjuFBVJA0tAREJKRhtu5UkDp4YK6PXAYjKZoE1nC0oG00J1ur1gAN1iMxs5JhAZnM4AsNssamtFptASdlP8bmcLiTCbcQPdHtoXnp3opPt9fhSVED6iDzM1Wu04FkYnkCkVbHATC1nIJZl0ev1BlRRhMprMcNsFikajkVPlnA84AcAez5qhBLj9ddKT4UuMUFBVHawJE2dtRHweD4YOMIM1pgB%20Z2GBqg27g3nQ-nlWIJJIm0XipCS6WwuWIxUo5UYlrGGCEBMQjSiCAQK3ObZWwQ2u0qB2Rf3mw0ut0er0%20usGraGTmNEMQqHcTzgHx%20KA0eOJuAyuEIoZp1Ho1WKLM5vO2AtFktqk1m9uWk2V%2009WvOxSu91IT3e8F%20gOsNiWOCnZzACDOADSSHY0wAPNEAHzuaIxWzBMpTgQDfTgRJ2AgcgwLgDRdQGKAAG47y4OAHCODBH2fZwbB4LgoB-bBoh%20Hh-xkbZALHUCUGcdhtggwCADI4EraoUB4L9kDQaBBC-ABRYw0H4VIvxwl930-H8yN-bAoJgsC5LgRDbF-f8EKQJDUOYAB6XSdgYU0YFmFQICQWYYAgTEYBgGY1H0g50HiCAkPIHgIAAdwAOl4kBdIARz4CzqhfaZdIANgAVgADgABiiiK4ri3SOC4ABaPgnxfdLnAgGB0rQBYEhqdLyGgdKTGhaZpnSsAplsaoLIAYjo6ZPNsdLoviqKAHYooAZjQ-trmw7LnB-CiMNGmAJLwpACNsYilNYXjnAOOAACE%20Fsl9HkIL88EiBhyDZUgpoACjwIrgB4QQGGcUgAEpZH-L9pjAOj-xuu6Hq-XSPq%201awvgQgUHAMYVHmqh3CuzdsRWFRsCXXNQygbAGD6YAkE8hxbWmbB1VNVwtR1JBME3DVXGwct92rQ9sFPZtLxM7BdjZ5Rzh4bBmR56kvh%20eBDEUDRMLiWbxq-AVSeFWMoGCCNsjiRIoBFeWQgHbxfH8X8no0ZB0BgbyDYwASfBAPNXoxBgYD4KBHou7ZFHet5cN-J3FFwInNSFXU4GY1jHc94O4C-U0%20g9kO4G6Vwhj4aYeHYOxzwASWcXVVeiYZchkHA8AAfXzyIYBAS5MS3Enfe4EhhajuBdPdqOntr4OcG91x-dYr9IgARl-NuK5UEh-t738W89nBadtA9HU70OwH7qeqxrYfdIX8fFBwJnzxbK856Duuw-hSOQ5jr4qHjxPk5gNOM6sLOc7zuBC%20L0uCybHeWdmGuT8UBuT%20bifL821dqPWOkgcgucyQ8BIP3XYq8QFWWcI3EOOBMbY1xsoKAswA5wAPlHL8iJKjVA7v-JuG9Q4pxAG4TiMBc7MkFmQdyzx6H8yQGQDyVMVAyAAESoHPjw%20uKDnYA1di%20OAKCnoGCAA)

Please read this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties) in order to understand whats going on.

**UPDATE**

You should be aware of that your union is not discriminated.
In order to do that, you should add unique property to each type:

```js
export interface AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: HeroStyling
  cta: string
  ctaUrl: string
  image: FluidObject
  imageAlt: string
}

export interface WithTagLineHeader extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: 'WithTagLineHeader' // unique
  headingTagLine: string
  heading: string
  leadParagraph: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}
export interface WithTickerHeader extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: 'WithTickerHeader' // unique
  textCenter: boolean
  leadParagraph?: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}

export interface SimpleForm extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: 'SimpleForm' // unique
  textCenter: boolean
  heading: string
  leadParagraph?: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}
export interface WithRating extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: 'WithRating' // unique
  textCenter: true
  reviewStars?: boolean
}
```

Full code:

```js
import React from 'react'
export type HeroStyling = 'SimpleForm' | 'WithTickerHeader' | 'WithTagLineHeader' | 'WithRating'

type FluidObject = {
  tag: 'FluidObject'
}
export interface AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: HeroStyling
  cta: string
  ctaUrl: string
  image: FluidObject
  imageAlt: string
}

export interface WithTagLineHeader extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: 'WithTagLineHeader'
  headingTagLine: string
  heading: string
  leadParagraph: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}
export interface WithTickerHeader extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: 'WithTickerHeader'
  textCenter: boolean
  leadParagraph?: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}

export interface SimpleForm extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: 'SimpleForm'
  textCenter: boolean
  heading: string
  leadParagraph?: string
  bulletPoints?: string
}
export interface WithRating extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  heroStyling: 'WithRating'
  textCenter: true
  reviewStars?: boolean
}

const CampaignHero = (props: WithTagLineHeader | WithTickerHeader | SimpleForm | WithRating): React.ReactElement => {
  if(props.heroStyling==='WithRating'){
    props.textCenter  // true
  }
  if(props.heroStyling==='WithTickerHeader'){
    props.textCenter // boolean
  }
  // etc ...
  return (
    <section>

    </section>
  )
}

<CampaignHero
  heroStyling={'WithRating'}
  reviewStars={true}
  textCenter={true}
  cta={hero.cta}
  ctaUrl={hero.ctaUrl}
  image={hero.image.fluid}
  imageAlt={hero.image.alt}
  bulletPoints={hero.bulletPoints} // expected error
/>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wCgkAPSWOGATzCTgAkkcBlegG2ADsBzOAF4C7UGC5IAYtBD44AHwIB1YDAAWAFWBoA1m1YoAJm3lL8qjZpT8AMnySGTUMyrXqEKGH35lS9RjgpLgBXYCMAeQAjACskDGE4AG9SOFobAC4CYLDI2PiYMgBfcipoeD4YNkx0JgBBIxQwbwA3RzYIAFkUPgAFHDAAZ2TUuHUOzjoeASzWDm4fUYwULMGYKEW05YBVKC5V9c24UBskLJzw6LiMUZP%20JDquGAONgVIS0uoK3iqoGrQmJYtDZ7Lx2sY2HBKFVeEZhg0mq12jhun0BsMUmlxvMpj4shZ3NY7A4nKZRuNjD4iaCznA1q9%20OTUEY8XTDm80pJjL0UFAbHywOoXkcoiEuJIYL0IJVBgB%20YVvEqUL7HH7VWpwIHaPQGZmQ6FIWHwxrNYBtOZdHq8foQIYjLETBYzNxWHT6KCklyjKoUGAAYUNvyyUQgEC5vFGXKMPL5-AF6nlbIZo1F4qQkulPzlCsZH2V5VVv3%20TDE4EkMigeANRrgCNN5o6qOt6PtY0duOd%20FLEmksjIaR9-sDbGDofDTMpzvpRyjMf5TQTOZTYolUplienis%20Bcq6oBmvcnm8AihvsNcNrJqRFqbNrtmLbOOm-HxQKPPn7tGhAbVUCy6xCJBRiIFpgCQAB3TheWzOAQzDVAIw%20NAIF4NY4D9FBwB6fheAtRIAAowHRLItRBEk9SgRQD1dHUPQoqju3LWQqLfLwfAASiyZB0BgAA6biMAAUUkEBA2EAA%20VtgEwQj0V47EIEmZ8hBUgkNHfAR8HYh80iI21Bl4wcf1%20NIAHpTNoKBANGEo0mk2T9Pk9tlNUrU3V1CEXG00ZdLkozh0o8zYLHBCbNGIL0zQOBeJi4D0xCKBeDgfCfLgAAeQYCmAFDxNIVK0tMzKMGy3hcrSdj3jytKMKw4AcItJknx8IQkjUjw2M02y4BAsDIJgaCWoApAuv839Bqs4aln6lqFN45Yup2PYZo6Ob%20t2LguruJBlpwXitt4zBQnCTaQFOR4YB2iA9tO%205eJQJ4utTVdMxgQZLt4p70zXLMijgCKqAKJAjChKAcCgUhTPEoA)

Comment: I have one question. This solution works perfectly and TS does not complain. However, when adding in the props for component rendering it still accepts all key values. I get a TS error only when there is a prop missing from the selected component type. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: @rockon_d please provide an example in your question. There are a lot of properties

Comment: Ive added an example to my question at the bottom of my question. Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please share `WithRating`. Try to share fully reproducible example without undefined types and variables

Comment: I did its below the SimpleForm class and everything is copy pasted from my original code. But here it is again to make it easier: 

export interface WithRating extends AdaptiveHeroMainProps {
  textCenter: true
  reviewStars?: boolean
}