# Typescript with multiple types, how to determine which type has certain props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Lets say I have 3 types. typeA, typeB, and typeC

typeA has a name property while typeB and typeC does not

when I render this with a code like;

```
interface propTypes {
 post: typeA | typeB | typeC
}

..... some react code ....
return( 
{post?.name && component})
```

But it returns an error: "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'typeA| typeB | typeC

I tried post instanceof typeA but it returns an error 'typeA' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: `{post && 'name' in post && component})` works?

Comment: Oh man you're a savior! Been searching for hours. Thanks man. can you add your answer below so that others who may have the same problem can see ho to fix this?

Comment: Already there's an answer mentioning this solution, so can be accepted 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
type typeA = {
  name: string
}

type typeB = {
  surname: string
}

type typeC = {
  age: number
}

type post = typeA | typeB | typeC

interface propTypes {
  post: post
}

const App = ({ post }: propTypes) => {
  post // no autocomplete

  return null
}
```

There is no autocomplete after `post.` because you don't have any common props.

See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#unions-with-common-fields)

> If we have a value that is a union type, we can only access members that are common to all types in the union.

In order to make it work, you should either define a [typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
const isTypeA = (props: unknown): props is typeA => Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(props, 'name')

const App = ({ post }: propTypes) => {
  if (isTypeA(post)) {
    post.name // string
  }

  return null
}
```

OR, you can use `in` operator, it works very nice with unions:

```js
const App = ({ post }: propTypes) => {
  if ('name' in post) {
    post.name // string
  }

  return null
}
```

OR you can use [`StrictUnion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) type:

```js
type typeA = {
  name: string
}

type typeB = {
  surname: string
}

type typeC = {
  age: number
}

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
  T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Post = StrictUnion<typeA | typeB | typeC>


interface propTypes {
  post: Post
}


const App = ({ post }: propTypes) => {
  if (post.name) {
    post.name // string
  }

  return null
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-beta#code/C4TwDgpgBKkIJQLxQN4CgpQHYEMC2EAXFAM7ABOAllgOZoC%20aas0LAQkqhqQK7m4FiZKrQZMWMcBADCndJhw0i2HngBGEcmOZSoAVSyUA9lgDSEECQA8AFQB8nG1AgAPYBCwATElCcB%20KABrCyMAM18oYiwIADdNAG4dSCgAZQpKAGNgA2MsAAkIABtIclsAGl84QsKHRG4nV3cvHxwsEG4ApwAyKAAFHHJgShxCqwAlCAyjck8rAFEXDMKeTwgrHJNzS1sqmorgkDDfOwrouPI7ByjYhPFdNKosjaxbWtT0p8MTAuLNcuO7slekYyJwHplsl8XiwEAAfSSQDjwljSOxMNDUdzkUI4DLQMDkIxgGxSHzyKBgEHAYjAsjaNBTLCguBgMCcAAUKApVKg9GIBKJJMgJAAlEgHOTKOF2ZSyAA6AQQMXkzCy4AK-DQAD0WtI6VEmEY3HIEGAfCwKmqDCAA)

---

> the 'in' operator worked for me
> Please keep in mind that it has own drawbacks:

```js
type typeA = {
  name?: string
}

interface propTypes {
  post: typeA
}


const App = ({ post }: propTypes) => {
  if ('name' in post) {
    post.name.charAt // error
  }

  return null
}
```

It works perfectly fine with unions, but not with optional properties.

Comment: the 'in' operator worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @BonAndreOpina sure, made an update about the drawback

Answer (score -1):

You can define types for each prop with a | sign, like the following:

```
import React, {ReactElement} from 'react';

interface propTypes {
  post: ReactElement | string;
}

const App = ({ post }: propTypes) => {
  post // no autocomplete

  return null
}
```