# Mapping a variable number of generics while retaining link between type values

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a factory function which creates a classic `on()` event listener, but one that is specific to whatever even types I want to allow the user to listen to. The events are defined as types and they have `eventName` and `data` (which is the data that is returned when the event emits). I would like to keep these two related to each-other, such that if I were to listen for a specific event then the relevant data will be available to me in the handler.

Consider this code:

```js
interface DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: string
  data: unknown
}

interface ChristmasEvent extends DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: 'christmas',
  data: {
    numberOfPresentsGiven: number
  }
}

interface EasterEvent extends DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: 'easter',
  data: {
    numberOfEggsGiven: number
  }
}

export function Listener <EventBody extends DefaultEventBody> () {

  return (eventName: EventBody['eventName'], fn: (data: EventBody['data']) => void) => {
    // someEmitter.on(eventName, fn)
  }
}

const spoiltBrat = { on: Listener<EasterEvent|ChristmasEvent>() }

spoiltBrat.on('christmas', (data) => {

  console.log(data.numberOfPresentsGiven)

})
```

TypeScript rightly knows that the `eventName` I pass can be `christmas|easter`, but it is unable to infer the `data` type on the handler, and subsequently errors when I attempt to access `data.numberOfPresentsGiven`.

> Property 'numberOfPresentsGiven' does not exist on type '{ numberOfPresentsGiven: number; } | { numberOfEggsGiven: number; }'.
> Property 'numberOfPresentsGiven' does not exist on type '{ numberOfEggsGiven: number; }'.(2339)

I'm aware of *why* this is happening (because neither of the types `ChristmasEvent` and `EasterEvent` contain the same `numberOf*` properties), but wondered if there was a solution to what I want to achieve?

### Update

As per the request from Captain Yossarian, here is a [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABCEDIJYGcAuBTAdigTgMQIYGMkB7TATwDokFIRgww41VMAzAlCAERTYFcAbJAFEAbuiQAhIgBNSEAN6QIKMUwByuALYoAXBGSZGAcyXTcSXHt5oA1miIB3NGAC+9FAA8ADiSQQW1oRwRGiwiKgYmAA8AIL8-I4o0qLiCMoeEdJp3HyCKUxSsgB8ABQAlBCgEACycvyMzBAOuExpxBB2jk0AFuYQAJIA5JoQmChIvJhoxhDdWBy0CvQQEEikXhz5VBAAvBBxCQ5JWwgA2oMq4hragwC6y6vrHADyYpgJuNLGaXuKKyunAAKmCIXggjAgJ1uehKl3UWl0EGBoIANP40DCzBY9EIMpgCEhYvFEslVFQ0fJlGTrojkWCXEVzljcHcKjsihAREQ4NI2RyuTylG4lGsNhAAGq4fi8FAIKIAFQ5e3lpxsKFIRBYEHl9xFTwgAFVpiFdhKpTK5a8sB8vmgjAgig9RRwjcE0PKiP0mFgECggiEogalRASgb0pk0i05AB+EM2PQGvmc7nSCB6DBvCqeCMhpQrePgtAsLADJRJgXSPMQWP9Kvpy6YADcTv1Jyt7yIn1NrpCHq9zF9-rQgeNaEdSjGEymIbhSBpegMxjRLAxIeZCdHfe9mEHSDdRMOxzJZ0GzLuRXLKaTiirVU4RH0ExYWtoDzcwtANAgAGEQgheJoxjwAARviZCUNQUB0Aw25sPgHDft0hjIJouAIFs4boFkXA8LgAjCGShRyH8VJXAieiDPgSHhKhCCDCipjmJYSz-BAaAAcBWDPCwwKyqkADicCqOmHFYEKrj0A0WBwZsaHMBh2ZYdkuH4VsREsaR8LaBRKByVg9GMdiGkrOxmicZg3FCEY9qCcJbGiZg4nCvgf5+AgPhwIIEj4n4vxKCEejwMg6BYFEiHIUgtEYQAPpCemYFspRlBJYDudyXk+eQIQlJR1EoWh9Frkx14PMy5CmeZ3G8b6rS2eglTAPZZliS4yWpR5GXmFlaA5bpwWYIVJTMiVKxlRVXEsFZNlCfVwCNeNjmtUAA) with the *almost* finished script.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick fix**

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753):

```js
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
  T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

export function Listener<EventBody extends DefaultEventBody>() {

  return (eventName: EventBody['eventName'], fn: (data: StrictUnion<EventBody['data']> /** <---- change is here */) => void) => {
    // someEmitter.on(eventName, fn)
  }
}


const spoiltBrat = {
  on: Listener<EasterEvent | ChristmasEvent>()
}

spoiltBrat.on('christmas', (data) => {
  data.numberOfPresentsGiven // <---- DRAWBACK, number | undefined
})
```

Above solution works but it has its own drawbacks. As you might have noticed, `numberOfPresentsGiven` is allowed but it might be `undefined`. This is not what we want.

**Longer fix**

Usually, if you want to type publish/subscribe logic, you should go with overloadings.
Consider this example:

```js
type AllowedEvents = ChristmasEvent | EasterEvent

type Events = AllowedEvents['eventName']

// type Overloadings = {
//     christmas: (eventName: "christmas", fn: (data: ChristmasEvent) => void) => void;
//     easter: (eventName: "easter", fn: (data: EasterEvent) => void) => void;
// }
type Overloadings = {
  [Prop in Events]: (eventName: Prop, fn: (data: Extract<AllowedEvents, { eventName: Prop }>) => void) => void
}
```

Now we have a data structure with appropriate types of our `on` function. On order to apply this DS to `on` and make it act as overloadings, we need to obtain a union type of `Overloadings` props and merge them (intersection). Why intersection ? Because intersection of function types produces overlodings.

Let's obtain a union of values:

```js
type Values<T>=T[keyof T]

type Union = 
| ((eventName: "christmas", fn: (data: ChristmasEvent) => void) => void) 
| ((eventName: "easter", fn: (data: EasterEvent) => void) => void)
type Union = Values<Overloadings>
```

Now, when we have a union, we can convert it to intersection with help of utility type:

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;
  
type EventsOverload = UnionToIntersection<Union>
```

**Temporary solution:**

```js
type AllowedEvents = ChristmasEvent | EasterEvent

type Events = AllowedEvents['eventName']


type Overloadings = {
  [Prop in Events]: (eventName: Prop, fn: (data: Extract<AllowedEvents, { eventName: Prop }>['data']) => void) => void
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Union = Values<Overloadings>


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type EventsOverload = UnionToIntersection<Union> & ((eventName: string, fn: (data: any) => void) => void)


export function Listener(): EventsOverload {

  return (eventName, fn: (data: any) => void) => {
    // someEmitter.on(eventName, fn)
  }
}


const spoiltBrat = {
  on: Listener()
}

spoiltBrat.on('christmas', (data) => {

  data.numberOfPresentsGiven // number
})

spoiltBrat.on('easter', (data) => {
  data.numberOfEggsGiven // number
})
```

However, it is not perfect yet. You propbably have noticed that I have used `any`. Nobody likes `any`. Instead of `any`, you can provide an intersection of all allowed `data` arguments:

```js
export function Listener(): EventsOverload {
  return (eventName, fn: (data: ChristmasEvent['data'] & EasterEvent['data']) => void) => {
  }
}
```

Why intersection ? Because this is the only safe way to handle any `eventName`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type/50375286#50375286) you can find more context and explanation.

**Whole solution:**

```js
interface DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: string
  data: unknown
}

interface ChristmasEvent extends DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: 'christmas',
  data: {
    numberOfPresentsGiven: number
  }
}

interface EasterEvent extends DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: 'easter',
  data: {
    numberOfEggsGiven: number
  }
}

type AllowedEvents = ChristmasEvent | EasterEvent

type Events = AllowedEvents['eventName']

type Overloadings = {
  [Prop in Events]: (eventName: Prop, fn: (data: Extract<AllowedEvents, { eventName: Prop }>['data']) => void) => void
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Union = Values<Overloadings>

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type EventsOverload = UnionToIntersection<Union>

export function Listener(): EventsOverload {
  return (eventName, fn: (data: UnionToIntersection<AllowedEvents['data']>) => void) => { }
}


const spoiltBrat = {
  on: Listener()
}

spoiltBrat.on('christmas', (data) => {

  data.numberOfPresentsGiven // number
})

spoiltBrat.on('easter', (data) => {
  data.numberOfEggsGiven // number
})
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wg68MW)

Here you have another example, taken from my [blog](https://catchts.com/publish-subscribe):

```js
const enum Events {
  foo = "foo",
  bar = "bar",
  baz = "baz",
}

/**
 * Single sourse of true
 */
interface EventMap {
  [Events.foo]: { foo: number };
  [Events.bar]: { bar: string };
  [Events.baz]: { baz: string[] };
}



type EmitRecord = {
  [P in keyof EventMap]: (name: P, data: EventMap[P]) => void;
};

type ListenRecord = {
  [P in keyof EventMap]: (
    name: P,
    callback: (arg: EventMap[P]) => void
  ) => void;
};

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;
  
type MakeOverloadings<T> = UnionToIntersection<Values<T>>;

type Emit = MakeOverloadings<EmitRecord>;
type Listen = MakeOverloadings<ListenRecord>;

const emit: Emit = <T,>(name: string, data: T) => { };

emit(Events.bar, { bar: "1" });
emit(Events.baz, { baz: ["1"] });
emit("unimplemented", { foo: 2 }); // expected error

const listen: Listen = (name: string, callback: (arg: any) => void) => { };

listen(Events.baz, (arg /* {baz: string[] } */) => { });
listen(Events.bar, (arg /* {bar: string } */) => { });
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WG6d9m)

Please keep in mind that your emitter and listener should have single sourse of true. I mean they shouls use shared event map.

---

**UPDATE**

It is a good practice to define your types in global scope. You almost never need to declare types inside function.

```js
/*
 * ListenerFactory.ts
 */

interface DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: string
  data: unknown
}
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

type Overloadings<E extends DefaultEventBody> = {
  [Prop in E['eventName']]: (eventName: Prop, fn: (data: Extract<E, { eventName: Prop }>['data']) => void) => void
}

export function Listener<AllowedEvents extends DefaultEventBody>(): UnionToIntersection<Values<Overloadings<AllowedEvents>>>
export function Listener<AllowedEvents extends DefaultEventBody>() {
  return (eventName: string, fn: (data: UnionToIntersection<AllowedEvents['data']>) => void) => { }
}

/*
 * ConsumingLibrary.ts
 */

interface ChristmasEvent extends DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: 'christmas',
  data: {
    numberOfPresentsGiven: number
  }
}

interface EasterEvent extends DefaultEventBody {
  eventName: 'easter',
  data: {
    numberOfEggsGiven: number
  }
}

const spoiltBrat = {
  on: Listener<ChristmasEvent | EasterEvent>()
}

spoiltBrat.on('christmas', (data) => {

  data.numberOfPresentsGiven // number
})

spoiltBrat.on('easter', (data) => {
  data.numberOfEggsGiven // number
})
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WyOxAN)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It's worked as you've said; and I need to devote some time to fully understanding it by going through the links you've sent a few times. My only problem with this is that `Listerner()` needs to be an exported factory function; meaning that I will pass in the `ChristmasEvent|EasterEvent` to it via a generic when calling it from another file. This means I need to block-scope the type setup (from `AllowedEvents` onwards). By doing that, I don't have a return type for `EventsOverload` as it has not been created yet. Any suggestions? +1 for now.

Comment: Could you please share min reproducible example with imports and comment what you have from third party library and what you need to type. I will try to help

Comment: Sure. Playground links are too long for the comments so please see link in updated answer. Essentially my linter wants to know what I'm returning from `Listener(): ?`. But I needed to block-scope `EventsOverload` in order to achieve a factory function, called from another file.

Comment: @shennan I made an update