# How to type tuple array with corresponding types?

Tags: typescript, tuples, typescript-generics, type-constraints, mapped-types

Could anyone help me with this unusual (as I think) problem?

Initially, I was implementing typed Map.

```js
export enum KeyType {
  aa = 'aa',
  bb = 'bb'
}

export interface ValueTypes {
  aa: boolean,
  bb: string
}

interface TypedMap extends Map<KeyType, ValueTypes[KeyType]> {
  get<TK extends KeyType>(k: TK): ValueTypes[TK] | undefined
  set<TK extends KeyType>(k: TK, v: ValueTypes[TK]): this
}
```

The code above works well. Then I wanted to implement a function that able to set multiple values to this map:

```js
function setMany<TKey, TVal> (
  map: Map<TKey, TVal>,
  change: (
    Map<TKey, TVal> |
    [TKey, TVal][]
  )
): void {
  const entries = change instanceof Map ? change.entries() : change

  for (const [key, value] of entries) {
    map.set(key, value)
  }
}
```

How can I type `[TKey, TVal][]` tuple array so that I have corresponding type check on input? Like:

```js
const tm = new Map() as TypedMap

setMany(
  tm,
  [
    [KeyType.aa, 'Foo'], // Error, aa requires boolean
    [KeyType.bb, 'Bar'] // Nice, bb requires string
  ]
)
```

As I understand, I need something like this:

```js
type ChangeTuple<TK extends KeyType> = [TK, ValueTypes[TK]]
```

but to work with argument and array. I tried this:

```js
interface setManyV2 {
  (
    map: TypedMap,
    change: (
      TypedMap |
      ChangeTuple[] // requires Generic type, but ChangeTuple<KeyType>[] doesn't work because TK doesn't extend anymore
    )
  ): void
}
```

Test cases:

```js
setMany(
  tm,
  [
    [KeyType.aa, true], // correct, aa requires boolean
    [KeyType.aa, false], // correct, aa requires boolean
    [KeyType.bb, 'any string'], // correct bb requires string
    [KeyType.aa, undefined], // incorrect, aa requires boolean, not undefined
    [KeyType.aa, new Set()], // incorrect, aa requires boolean, not Set
    [KeyType.aa, 'any string'], // incorrect, aa requires boolean, not string
    [KeyType.bb, new Set()], // incorrect, aa requires string, not Set
    [KeyType.bb, undefined], // incorrect, aa requires string, not undefined
    [KeyType.bb, false], // incorrect, aa requires string, not boolean
    [KeyType.bb, true] // incorrect, aa requires string, not boolean
  ]
)

const tm2 = new Map() as TypedMap

tm2.set(KeyType.aa, true)
tm2.set(KeyType.bb, 'string')

setMany(
  tm,
  tm2
)
```

Comment: Your first example causes an errors

Comment: What if you use `ChangeTuple<KeyType>[]` in the `setManyV2` interface?

Comment: @Dahou then it will accept `[KeyType.aa | KeyType.bb, boolean | string]` for all tuples which is unacceptable - I need one of `[KeyType.aa, boolean]` or `[KeyType.bb, string]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you want to overload your `Map` implementation by `TypedMap`. If yes, there is a better way to do it.

In order to overload your `Map` you need to intersect `Map` types, like this: `Map<'a', boolean> & Map<'b', string>`.

Since you have `KeyType` and `ValueTypes`, we can merge them into one data structure:

```js
type MapOverloading<Keys extends string, Values extends Record<Keys, unknown>> = {
    [Prop in Keys]: Map<Prop, Values[Prop]>
}


// type TypedMap = {
//     aa: Map<KeyType.aa, boolean>;
//     bb: Map<KeyType.bb, string>;
// }
type TypedMap = MapOverloading<KeyType, ValueTypes>
```

Now in order to produce Map overloading, we need to obtain a union of `TypedMap` object values.
It is simple, just use this util:

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
```

Now we need to convert union to intersection (`UnionToIntersection`):

```js
// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type MapOverloading<Keys extends string, Values extends Record<Keys, unknown>> = {
    [Prop in Keys]: Map<Prop, Values[Prop]>
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type TypedMap = UnionToIntersection<Values<MapOverloading<KeyType, ValueTypes>>>
```

More about creating dynamic overloadings you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70137328/mapping-a-variable-number-of-generics-while-retaining-link-between-type-values/70138046#70138046)
`TypedMap` is an overloaded `Map` data structure. Lets' test it:

```js
const tm: TypedMap = new Map();

tm.set(KeyType.aa, true) // ok
tm.set(KeyType.bb, true) // expected error
```

COnsider this example:

```js
export enum KeyType {
    aa = 'aa',
    bb = 'bb'
}

export interface ValueTypes {
    aa: boolean,
    bb: string
}


// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

type MapOverloading<Keys extends string, Values extends Record<Keys, unknown>> = {
    [Prop in Keys]: Map<Prop, Values[Prop]>
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type TypedMap = UnionToIntersection<Values<MapOverloading<KeyType, ValueTypes>>>

const tm: TypedMap = new Map();

tm.set(KeyType.aa, true) // ok
tm.set(KeyType.bb, true) // expected error

type IsNever<T> = [T] extends [never] ? true : false

type TupleToMap<Tuple extends any[], ResultMap extends Map<any, any> = never> =
    Tuple extends []
    ? ResultMap
    : Tuple extends [[infer Key, infer Value], ...infer Rest]
    ? IsNever<ResultMap> extends true ? TupleToMap<Rest, Map<Key, Value>> : TupleToMap<Rest, ResultMap & Map<Key, Value>>
    : never

type Validation<Tuple extends any[], CustomMap> = CustomMap extends TupleToMap<Tuple> ? Tuple : []

function setMany<
    Key extends string,
    Value,
    CustmoMap extends Map<Key, Value>,
    Tuple extends [Key, Value],
    Change extends Tuple[],
    >(
        map: CustmoMap,
        change: Validation<[...Change], CustmoMap>,
): void {

    for (const [key, value] of change) {
        map.set(key, value)
    }
}

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.aa, true], // ok
        [KeyType.aa, false] // ok
    ]
)

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.bb, 's'], // ok
        [KeyType.bb, 'hello'], // ok
    ]
)

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.bb, 's'], // ok
        [KeyType.aa, true, // ok
    ]
)

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.aa, undefined] // expected error
    ]
)

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.aa, new Set()] // expected error
    ]
)

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.bb, undefined] // expected error
    ]
)

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.bb, new Set()] // expected error
    ]
)

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.bb, false] // expected error
    ]
)
setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.bb, true] // expected error
    ]
)

setMany(
    tm,
    [
        [KeyType.aa, 'any string'] // expected error
    ]
)
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2Ek8W)
Above example answers on your first question: How to make it work with tuples.

However there is a drawback, if one of tuple element is invalid, whole tuple will be highlighted

Please let me know if it works for you. If it is, I will provide more explanation.

Comment: Wow, interesting. But setMany function detects TKey as KeyType.bb and TVal as string and doesn't accept aa and boolean tuple. It seems that it works with only one of Map types in intersection.

Comment: @ФилиппФастер please provide test cases . What you expect to work and what you expect to fail. It will be easier for me

Comment: `setMany(tm, [[KeyType.aa, true], [KeyType.aa, false], [KeyType.bb, 'anystring']])`.
So it should accept tuples with KeyType and its corresponding ValueTypes type.
I've tried to fix it myself, but I stuck on the same misunderstanding - I don't know how to type tuple properly:)

Comment: @ФилиппФастер made update for tuples. Do you expect second argument to be a map as well? If yes what type of map it should be? The same as first argument?

Comment: Yes, I expect the same Map type as the second argument, but... Now in the example setMany accepts `[KeyType.bb, true]` too.
I thought that it's obvious, but I understand my mistake, sorry. Here is full list or input test cases: see next comment V

Comment: Ok, I can't place it in a comment :D Please check question description at the end to see full list of test cases. (wrong cases too)

Comment: @PhilippFaster please let me know if it works for your first part of the question

Comment: Yes, sure. Thank you a lot. I've a deadline now. I'll reply in a while :)

Comment: Wow, sorry for so long delay. How this solution is great! Thank you a lot!