# Getting error with type using Typescript union

Tags: typescript, union-types

```
type myType = { subtitle: string, title: string } | {};

const someVar: myType = { title: 'some-title', subtitle: 'some subtitle'}

const myTitle: string = someVar?.title;
```

I get this type error when I try to access `title` value from `someVar` object. Now, what I don't understand is why wouldI get this type error. I checked the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) but I don't understand its implication. Union means I can specify possible types but here behaviour seems to be different. Any idea why's that

```
Property 'title' does not exist on type '{} | { subtitle: string; title: string; }'.
  Property 'title' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, what I don't understand is why wouldI get this type error.

Because `{}` doesn't have a property called `title`, and you've said that `someVar`'s type is `myType`, which is either `{ subtitle: string, title: string }` or `{}`. Since it might be `{}`, you can't access `title` without first making sure it's there. From [the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types):

> TypeScript will only allow you to do things with the union if that thing is valid for *every* member of the union.

Accessing `title` isn't valid for `{}`, just `{ subtitle: string, title: string }`.

To use `title`, you can use a type guard to narrow the type (details about narrowing [here in the handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html)):

```
if ("title" in someVar) {
    // ...you can use `someVar.title` (and/or `someVar.subtitle`) here...
}
```

Within that `if` body, TypeScript knows that `someVar`'s type is `{ subtitle: string, title: string }`, not `{}`, thanks to the condition.

[captain-yossarian points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70363426/getting-error-with-type-using-typescript-union/70363485#comment124381157_70363485) that [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) may be useful to read through as well, around how excess property checks apply to unions and the `StrictUnion` flag.

Comment: I think it worth adding quote from the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#unions-with-common-fields) about common fields. Also [StrictUnion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753)  might help in this use case

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Thanks! I was adding some docs links. I've also added a note about that question and `StrictUnion`.