# Using Properties on Typescript multitype declarations

Tags: typescript

is there better way got check existing properties in TypeScript instead of this?

```
x = obj["prop"] || "default";
```

Since its possible meanwhile (even in Swagger) to get Arrays consisting of different Object its becoming more and more an issue for me.

E.g.

```
let obj: {a:string, b?:string} | {a:string, c?:string};
obj = {a:"fuu", c:"baa"};

let x:string = obj.c; //err: no property "c" on possible object
let x:string = obj.c! || obj.b! || "default"; //err not possible
let x:string = obj["b"] || obj["c"] || "default"; //possible solution but looks bad for me cause the string access
```

Is there a good way to handle this which I missed?

Comment: `obj.b` is not allowed because it is not a common property in the union. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) answer

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJRolW) meet your needs?  The compiler doesn't know that there won't be a `b` property on a value of type `{a: string, c?: string}`, so it treats it as type `any` and gives an error.  If you say `{a: string, b?: never, c?: string}` it will work.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it helps very much. Thanks for that. Didnt knew the "never" type before. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
interface foo {
    a?:string;
    b?:string;
    c?:string;
}

let a: foo = {a:"a", c:"c"};
console.log(a.a);
```

Comment: Almost. It reduces the type to the commons. But the different extensions would be lost in scope. 
But how about extending the idea:

with something like:
`interface combo extends foo, bar {}`
? 

Opinions?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that object types in TypeScript are not "sealed".  A value of type `{a: string}` must have a string-valued `a` property, but it *may* have all sorts of extra properties.  The value `{a: "hello", z: "goodbye"}` is assignable to the `{a: string}` type.  Yes, the compiler will sometimes warn on [excess properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) attempt to prevent you from accidentally throwing away information about such properties:

```
const v: { a: string } = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" }; // error!
// ----------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Object literal may only specify known properties, 
//     and 'b' does not exist in type '{ a: string; }'
```

But this is more like a linter rule than a type safety check:

```
const w = { a: "hello", b: "goodbye" };
const v2: { a: string } = w; // okay
```

The compiler will only let you index into an object type with keys that are known to be valid:

```
v2.a; // okay
v2.b; // error, Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'
```

but that doesn't mean there is definitely no property at that key, and the compiler will treat such a property as being of [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) instead of something like [the `undefined` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined).

---

So a big problem with the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `{ a: string, b?: string } | { a: string, c?: string }` is that neither `b` nor `c` are known to be valid keys.  A value of type `{a: string, b?: string}` *might* have a `c` property of any type, and a value of type `{a: string, c?: string}` *might* have a `b` property of any type.

Again, usually this doesn't happen because of excess property checking, but again, such checking is not enforcing type safety, and can be avoided:

```
function foo(obj: { a: string, b?: string } | { a: string, c?: string }) { }
const oops = { a: "fuu", b: 123, c: "hello" }
foo(oops) // no error
```

You wouldn't want the implementation of `foo()` to assume that `obj.b` is either a `string` or `undefined`.  If it did, then you could write `obj.b?.toUpperCase()` and get a runtime error when `foo(oops)` is called.  Oops.

---

My inclination here would be to take the assumption that `b` and `c` are mutually exclusive and make it explicit:

```
function foo(obj: 
  { a: string, b?: string, c?: never } | 
  { a: string, b?: never, c?: string }
 ): string {
  return obj.c || obj.b || "default"; // okay
}
```

So instead of `{a: string, b?: string}` we have `{a: string, b?: string, c?: never}` where [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is a type has no possible values.  If you read from the `c` property, you will definitely get an `undefined` value (because you can't get a `never` one).  So now you are allowed to check the `b` property because each member of the union has known behavior at the `b` property.  (The analogous thing holds for the `c` property).

Now you can write `obj.c || obj.b || "default"` with impunity, because `obj.c` is of type `string | undefined`, and so is `obj.b`, and thus the full expression is of type `string`.

This explicit version means that `foo()` accepts known good inputs

```
foo({ a: "fuu", c: "baa" });
```

and rejects the bad `oops` input from before:

```
const oops = { a: "fuu", b: 123, c: "hello" }
foo(oops) //  error now
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJLwD2wUALkgG4BceSITNATgJbADmSAvkgC8zVkgBEACwgYM5cQBokAIybie5cgBNlATwjiBAbiQB6U0gjt25dgEISZiwFpXb9x89fPAPiQA-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-QIcwPJ8IycUgrFjEF4yIfggA)