# TypeScript + React: Trying to write a component that accepts two types of props but I end up only being able to access the common prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to have a component `Foo` that accepts two types of props:

1. `Foo({a: 'a'})`
2. `Foo({a: 'a', b: 'b', c:'c'})`

where `{a: 'a'}` is required.

These should invalid

```
Foo({a: 'a', b: 'b'}) // ❌
Foo({a: 'a', c: 'c'}) // ❌
```

Here is my attempt.

```js
type BaseProps = {
  a: "a";
};

type VariantPrps = {
  b: "b";
  c: "c";
} & BaseProps;

function Foo(props: BaseProps): React.ReactNode;
function Foo(props: VariantPrps): React.ReactNode;

function Foo(props: BaseProps | VariantPrps) {
  // I can only access `props.a` inside
  return <span>{props.a}</span>;
}



// usage
Foo({a: 'a'}) // ✅
Foo({a: 'a', b: 'b', c:'c'}) // ✅

Foo({a: 'a', b: 'b'}) // ❌
Foo({a: 'a', c: 'c'}) // ❌
```

it works to some extent but inside `Foo` I can only access `a`, not `b` and `c`. My intention is that inside that component I should be able to access `b` and `c` and **check to see if they exist or not** before using them. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```js
import React from 'react'

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
    T extends any
    ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type BaseProps = {
    a: "a";
};

type VariantPrps = {
    b: "b";
    c: "c";
} & BaseProps;

function Foo(props: BaseProps): React.ReactNode;
function Foo(props: VariantPrps): React.ReactNode;

function Foo(props: StrictUnion<BaseProps | VariantPrps>) {
    props.a // "a"
    props.b // "b" | undefined
    props.c // "c" | undefined
    // I can only access `props.a` inside
    return <span>{props.a}</span>;
}



// usage
Foo({ a: 'a' }) // ✅
Foo({ a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' }) // ✅

Foo({ a: 'a', b: 'b' }) // ❌
Foo({ a: 'a', c: 'c' }) // ❌
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N9yQ7N)

You were allowed to use only `a` property because it is common property for both types.
See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#working-with-union-types)

Comment: hmm this is really complicated... I thought I can some discriminated type to distinguish them?

Comment: @Joji ... This is suitable in case we can't afford a `discriminant` in the types.

Comment: @Joji then just add discriminator tag

Comment: @captain-yossarian I cannot seem to figure out how

Comment: @Joji see [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxBy8w) example

Comment: @captain-yossarian hmm thanks for the reply but in the branch for `VariantProps` we still cannot access `props.b` and `props.c` right?

Comment: @Joji my bad, you should make `tag` property required. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/w16GGN)