# Typescript. Can I define conditional types?

Tags: typescript

Imagine I have the following type

```
type BannerConditions = {
    publication_id?: number;
    product_id?: number;
    resource?: string;
    type: string;
  };
```

But publication_id and product_id can only exist if resource exists. Can I define it somehow?

Comment: Because TS has structural type system, you need to use extra type utility helper to handle this kind of union type. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/mAj2RW) and great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) with explanation

Comment: I'd willing to bet that this question is a duplicate.  Are you agree ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a union to describe the two type

```
type BannerConditions = {
    publication_id: number;
    product_id: number;
    resource: string;
    type: string;
  } | {
    publication_id: undefined;
    product_id: undefined;
    resource: undefined;
    type: string;
}
```

```
// foo would throw an error
const foo: BannerConditions = {
  publication_id: 1,
  product_id: 2,
  resource: undefined,
    type: 'x'
}
// no error for bar
const bar: BannerConditions = {
  publication_id: 1,
  product_id: 2,
  resource: 'test',
  type: 'x'
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgOwRATgYQPYICYEti5YDOUAvFAN4BQUtUYArgEYA2uAxnAVgPq7YAuKAgYBbJqgDcNOmBQZsDdsD6DhYiSml0oKCEQwMU7CEKLAUuBAHNtdUJDMWrtmQF8oAH0ozajVhxchAiqQgw4EABmVhDYdn7yisqhUOHYUTFxvrr6hsamqRHRyFk6DgXmljZ2HlQy7MTAUJEYGELwSKiYOPjBJOTUOkP0zGyc3CH8QgCMADTZwwkKSipTUABM84tDegZGJmFFmVvb9uAFAOQAHhfudToNCOZQTHAo7YjI6Fh4E-0%20pxGAXGwRScwWizky2Sa02EOGuzyBygF2A%20mAFxOgPKQmut1obiAA)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: merge them as required properties in a separate optional object:

```
type BannerConditions = {
  type: string;
  resource?: {
    publication_id: number;
    product_id: number;
    type: string;
  };
};
```

I changed `resource` to `type` since `resource.resource` seems to be a bit odd. `BannerConditions` could also be an interface rather than a type.