# Param type resolution when combining union and intersection types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, union-types

Here are 3 simple types

```
type T1 =
  | { letter: 'a'; valueFunc: (prop: number) => void; valueType: number }
  | { letter: 'b'; valueFunc: (prop: string) => void; valueType: string }

type T2 = { base: 'low' }

type T3 = T1 & T2
```

And 2 simple definitions

```
const var1: T3 = { letter: 'b', base: 'low', valueFunc: (prop) => {}, valueType: 'empty' }

const var2: T3 = { letter: 'a', base: 'low', valueFunc: (prop) => {}, valueType: 0 }
```

This works perfectly as expected. TS correctly evaluates the types of `prop` in the `valueFunc`. However, if I add another type union to `T2`, TS is no longer able to resolve `prop` but it can still resolve `valueType`.

Modified types

```
type T1 =
  | { letter: 'a'; valueFunc: (prop: number) => void; valueType: number }
  | { letter: 'b'; valueFunc: (prop: string) => void; valueType: string }

type T2 = { base: 'low' } | {noise: 'high'}

type T3 = T1 & T2

const var1: T3 = { letter: 'b', base: 'low', valueFunc: (prop) => {}, valueType: 'empty' }

const var2: T3 = { letter: 'a', noise: 'high', valueFunc: (prop) => {}, valueType: 0 }
```

Why is that? What am I missing?

Comment: Typescript inference has limitations and the heuristics it uses do not cover all possible scenarios - for complex cases you need type annotations: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript works very well with  [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions)

`T1` is discriminated, because each union has `letter` property, whereas `T2` is not. You have two ways to resolve this issue.

**First way**
Just add `discriminator` to `T2`, for example:

```js
type T2 = { type: '1', base: 'low' } | { type: '2', noise: 'high' }
```

**Second way**
Make your `T2` union more strict. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) for more explanation:

```js
type T1 =
  | { letter: 'a'; valueFunc: (prop: number) => void; }
  | { letter: 'b'; valueFunc: (prop: string) => void; }


type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
  T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type T2 = StrictUnion<{ base: 'low' } | { noise: 'high' }>

type T3 = T1 & T2

const var1: T3 = { letter: 'b', base: 'low', valueFunc: (prop) => { } } // prop is string

const var2: T3 = { letter: 'a', noise: 'high', valueFunc: (prop) => { } } // prop is number
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w65yrW)

Rule of thumb:
If you have a union where each object is different and has nothing in common - add discriminator.

**More explanation**

1)

> Why we use `UnionKeys` instead of `keyof T`

We can use `T extends any` as well. The main point here it to use conditional typings for [distributivity](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). Why ? Because when you use `keyof ({a:1}|{b:2})` you will get `never` because they don't share common properties. See [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions).

It means that when you are using:

```js
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends any ? keyof T : never;
```

`keyof T` is applied to each element in a union separately and not to whole union only because we have used here `T extends any`.

In general you should treat `T extends any` - as `turn on distributivity` and `[T] extends [any]` - as check it without distributivity.

P.S. You can check my [blog](https://catchts.com/unions) for more interesting examples

Comment: Wow!.. I am playing with it to understand it better.. could you help me understand why we use `UnionKeys` instead of `keyof T`? Also, why use conditional when we know `T extends T` the same with `T extends any`?

Comment: Btw, feel free tp use `T extrnds any` as well as `T extends T`. In this case - it does not matter. We do conditional typing only for triggering distributivity

Comment: I was wondering if this can be simplified to `type StrictUnion<T, U = T> = T extends T ? U & Partial<Record<keyof T, never>> : never` but that does not work for `undefined` types. The best one can do is remove the excessive support types and leave it at `type StrictUnion<T, U = T> = T extends T
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<U extends U ? keyof U : never, keyof T>, never>>
  : never`

Comment: @Lordbalmon I understand why you want to reduce it, but in TS, reduced version of type is hard to read and maintain.

Comment: Now that you mention it .. I absolutely agree!