# Typescript access a property a union type in which not all members have said property

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following code:

```
interface A {
    a: number;
}

interface B extends A {
    b: number;
}

const instanceOfB: B = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
}

const myFunct = (arg: A | B) => {
    const myNumber = arg.b ?? 42;
    console.log(myNumber);
};

myFunct(instanceOfB);
```

Inside `myFunct` I want to access the `b` property of `arg`, which might or might not exist on `arg` depending on whether or not `arg` is of type `B`. In case it does not exist and the access returns `undefined`, I use the fallback value of `42`.
Typescript complains that `Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A | B'.`, which is true. `A | B` is basically the same as `A` since only `a` is shared between them both, yet I would still like to try to access it and use my fallback value if it doesn't.
I know I could change my JavaScript to satisfy Typescript by changing the relevant line to e.g. `const myNumber = "b" in arg ? arg.b : 42;`, but I really don't want to change my JavaScript code just to make Typescript happy when my code is (in my opinion) perfectly fine.

Is there a Typescript only solution to my Typescript only problem?

Also, if someone knows, I would be very interested in why Typescript complains about `arg.b ?? 42` but not `"b" in arg ? arg.b : 42`.

Comment: Just use `in` operator in this case. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/mq5Kqm). `in` operator works well with unions or try [StrictUnion](https://tsplay.dev/w2ad1W) helper. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) answer

Answer (score 0):

The `??` operator goes to the "otherwise" case for both `null` and `undefined` values. In other words, it's not the same as checking for the existence of a key.

`"b" in arg` works because `in` will return true for a key that has been set to `null` or `undefined`:

```js
const arg = { a: undefined }
console.log(arg.a ?? "not in") // not in
console.log("a" in arg ? "in" : "not in") // in
```

`arg.a ??` accesses the value of `a`, but `arg` may not have an `a` property, so TypeScript tells you that. `"a" in arg` doesn't access `arg.a`, it checks to see *if* it exists.