# typescript - how to optionally intersect with a type

Tags: typescript

I have
`type Action = {actionText: string, onClick: VoidFunction}`

and I want to use it, optionally, inside `MyComponent` props so `MyComponent` can have an action (and then it must get both `actionText` and `onClick` props) or it may not have an action (and then it doesn't get any of them)

so the result will be something like:
`type MyComponentType = {title: string} & [optional]Action`

what is the best way to do it?

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4nJw) you have a working eample. See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) answer for more context

Comment: it works, thanks! but, can you explain why all this code is necessary and not just `type OptionalIntersection<T, O> = T | (T & O);`

Comment: Because `Partial<O>&T` will be assignable to `T`. From what I understood, you want either `T` or `T & O` but not partial solution.v TypeScript is structural typed language.