# Why undeclared field in union type can be filled with declared field type

Tags: typescript

code as follow

My expected is if `b` is not declared, there should be no `b` in the assigned value.

My another expected is if `b` is not declared, there should be any `b` in the assigned value， but also `c` `d` ...

```js
type Target =
  | {
      a: 1;
    }
  | {
      a: 2;
      b: number;
    }
  | {
      a: 3;
      b: boolean;
    };


// The result is 

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  // correct
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1, // correct
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: "true", // incorrect
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: true, // correct
};

// My expected result is

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  // correct
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1, // incorrect
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: "true", // incorrect
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: true, // incorrect
};


// My another expected result is

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  // correct
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1, // correct
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: "true", // correct
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  b: true, // correct
};

const target: Target = {
  a: 1,
  c: true, // correct
};
```

How can this be completed?

Comment: add `b?: never` to the first union element

Comment: @TobiasS. That's right ,then how can another expected problem be completed?

Comment: Try [StrictUnion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) util