# Require exactly two of three properties with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a few React components that need exactly two of three props to represent a time range: `from`, `to`, or `duration`. Any combination of two is enough to derive the third one correctly. So I want TypeScript to enforce that exactly two of these props is required.

I tried defining props like this:

```
type RangeProps =
  | {
      from: Date
      to: Date
    }
  | {
      from: Date
      duration: number
    }
  | {
      duration: number
      to: Date
    }
```

But when I supply all three props (`<Range from={startDate} duration={duration} to={endDate} />`, TypeScript doesn't complain. How can I get it to complain?

Comment: https://dev.to/maissenayed/conditional-react-props-with-typescript-43lg I think you can apply this solution for `trom,to,duration`?

Comment: The non-combinatorial-complexity way to do it is to add a new `kind` key to each,  and give each `kind` a unique number of string value:   `type RangeProps =
  | { kind: 1,
      from: Date,
      to: Date
    }
  | { kind: 2,
      from: Date,
      duration: number
    }`

Comment: Please see [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaDXpw) example.  Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753) answer for more information

Answer (score 2):

You can use the type `never`, this type means that the property cannot be passed:

```
type RangeProps =
  | {
      from: Date;
      to: Date;
      duration?: never;
    }
  | {
      from: Date;
      duration: number;
      to?: never;
    }
  | {
      duration: number;
      to: Date;
      from?: never;
    };
```

Comment: [While this code may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2887218)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASghgOwOYQAoCcD2YDOUC8AUFCVAD5QDexptAZlgLYBcUAInMBDbScJqw5ceUAL4iK1XqQaYW7Tt2kkAJgFd0nAJaYErBGsYAjCOhHjakkbXWbgOvVAPHT10v0GLzhQgGNdOMBQcEa+BFAAPAAqUBAAHlwIKnjwyGhYuAB8ABQAbqwx8YnJThC5plAA-FAxrADksox15FB1-M0Udbbaus1FEEl4ANYQIJh0NVVQAEQAouhY6Kxwvr4QYMB4AExQYBl4ugA2INNQBQCUBJlUPuIhvtmUUI36EADuClzZ5wA0UB6lD5CCDfMTnQj3R7-ASAz4g35Qbr2XSsACMWwAzGCIaEoS9YcDvn8kQ40ZjsQB6CmEKk06m0hn06mQp74hDvOFE6GvIGKLkklFQdFY0TnIA)

use this generic trick `T extends never? T : some type check logic`

`T extends any? some type check logic : never` also work

Comment: Interested to understand what's going on here

Comment: I use this trick a lot to create custom error message but I don't know why it works