# Pass exact type through the function but validate extra fields

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want a component to expose the function that accepts a constant object (i.e. enum) of types. Let's say this type is `Test`.

If the function will accept `Record<string, Test>`, the relation between names and `Test` objects would be lost. But if you try to pass an object with an extra field, compiler will throw `TS2345`

If the function will accept generic parameter `T` which `extends Record<string, Test>`, the relation will be saved, but extra fields will not cause compilation error anymore.

If this is a library method used by others, it will obscure the whole bunch of errors caused by typos from the library users.

Is there any option in between this two I miss?

```
type Test = {
  field: number
}

function a(param: Record<string, Test>) {
  return param;
}

function b<T extends Record<string, Test>>(param: T) {
  return param;
}

const x = a({
  first: {
    field:     13,
    notExists: -1, // TS2345:  Object literal may only specify known properties, and not_exists does not exist in type Test
  },
} as const);

const y = b({
  first: {
    field:     42,
    notExists: -1, // I want this line to throw compile-time error
  },
} as const);

type xa = typeof x['first']['field']; // number
type xb = typeof y['first']['field']; // 42

// And keep finding 42 instead of number in type above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
type Test = {
  field: number
}

function a(param: Record<string, Test>) {
  return param;
}

type Validation<T extends Record<string, Test>> = {
  [Prop in keyof T]: {
    /**
     * Iterate through keys of root properties
     * If a Key dont extends 'field' it means that it is anvialid key
     * and we can assign 'never' type to it so it will be unrepresentable
     */
    [Key in keyof T[Prop]]: Key extends 'field' ? T[Prop][Key] : never
  }
}
const b = <
  const Field extends Test,
  T extends Record<string, Field>
>(param: Validation<T>) => param

const x = b({
  first: {
    field: 13,
    notExists: -1, // TS2345:  Object literal may only specify known properties, and not_exists does not exist in type Test
  },
});


type xb = typeof x['first']['field'] // 13
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqq6Qm)

You need to iterate through Test object type and assign `never` to each non `field` key.

> That would not work if, for example, type Test = {a: number; b: number} | {c: number, d: number}

COnsider this:

```js
// taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65805600/type-union-not-checking-for-excess-properties#answer-65805753
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> =
  T extends any
  ? T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, never>> : never;

type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Test = StrictUnion<{ a: number; b: number } | { c: number, d: number }>

const b = <
  const Field extends Test,
  T extends Record<string, Field>
>(param: T) => param

const x = b({
  first: {
    a: 1,
    b: 1,
  },
});


type xb = typeof x['first']['a'] // 1
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBY7kw)

Comment: That would not work if, for example, `type Test = {a: number; b: number} | {c: number, d: number}`, but thanks for the idea

Comment: @Grief answer is updated

Comment: Clever! That works for my case. If I find something, I'll leave a comment. Thank you very much for the help!